# T-SQL trim &nbsp (and other non-alphanumeric characters)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have some input data that sometimes appears with &nbsp characters on the end.

The data comes in from the source system as varchar() and our attempts to cast as decimal fail b/c of these characters.

Ltrim and Rtrim don't remove the characters, so we're forced to do something like:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = replace(myColumn,char(160),'')
WHERE charindex(char(160),myColumn) > 0
```

This works for the &nbsp, but is there a good way to do this for any non-alphanumeric (or in this case numeric) characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This page](http://www.lazydba.com/sql/1__4390.html) has a sample of how you can remove non-alphanumeric chars:

```
-- Put something like this into a user function:
DECLARE @cString    VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @nPos    INTEGER
SELECT  @cString = '90$%45623 *6%}~:@'
SELECT  @nPos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @cString)

WHILE @nPos > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @cString = STUFF(@cString, @nPos, 1, '')
SELECT  @nPos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @cString)
END

SELECT @cString
```

Comment: this removes all but 0-9 (numbers). .... so it's not really doing _alpha_ numberic :P  ..

Answer (score 17):

This will remove all non alphanumeric chracters

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemoveBadCharacter]
(
    @BadString nvarchar(20)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

            DECLARE @nPos INTEGER
            SELECT @nPos = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9_]%', @BadString)

            WHILE @nPos > 0
            BEGIN
                        SELECT @BadString = STUFF(@BadString, @nPos, 1, '')
                        SELECT @nPos = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9_]%', @BadString)
            END

            RETURN @BadString
END
```

Use the function like:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate
SET ColumnToUpdate = dbo.fnRemoveBadCharacter(ColumnToUpdate)
WHERE whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

How is the table being populated?  While it is possible to scrub this in sql a better approach would be to change the column type to int and scrub the data before it's loaded into the database (SSIS).  Is this an option?

Answer (score 0):

For large datasets I have had better luck with this function that checks the ASCII value. I have added options to keep only alpha, numeric or alphanumeric based on the parameters.

```
--CleanType 1 - Remove all non alpanumeric
--          2 - Remove only alpha
--          3 - Remove only numeric
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCleanString] (
        @InputString    varchar(8000)
    ,   @CleanType      int 
    ,   @LeaveSpaces    bit 
)   RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS 
BEGIN

    -- // Declare variables
    -- ===========================================================
    DECLARE @Length     int
        ,   @CurLength  int = 1
        ,   @ReturnString varchar(8000)=''

    SELECT @Length = len(@InputString)

    -- // Begin looping through each char checking ASCII value
    -- ===========================================================
    WHILE (@CurLength <= (@Length+1))
    BEGIN
        IF  (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputString,@CurLength,1)) between 48 and 57      AND @CleanType in (1,3) )
        or  (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputString,@CurLength,1))    between 65 and 90   AND @CleanType in (1,2) )
        or  (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputString,@CurLength,1))    between 97 and 122  AND @CleanType in (1,2) )
        or  (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputString,@CurLength,1))    = 32    AND @LeaveSpaces = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnString = @ReturnString + SUBSTRING(@InputString,@CurLength,1)
        END
        SET @CurLength = @CurLength + 1
    END

    RETURN  @ReturnString
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile could start with a Plus(+) I will use the function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Mobile_NoAlpha](@Mobile VARCHAR(1000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartsWithPlus BIT = 0

    --check if the mobile starts with a plus(+)
    IF LEFT(@Mobile, 1) = '+'
    BEGIN
        SET @StartsWithPlus = 1

        --Take out the plus before using the regex to eliminate invalid characters
        SET @Mobile = RIGHT(@Mobile, LEN(@Mobile)-1) 
    END

    WHILE PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Mobile) > 0 
        SET @Mobile = Stuff(@Mobile, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Mobile), 1, '')  

    IF @StartsWithPlus = 1
        SET @Mobile = '+' + @Mobile
    RETURN @Mobile 
END
```