# Removing characters after numbers in a column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, charindex

I want to delete the characters after numbers in one of my columns:

Column values are like this :

```
2GB 
3G
28GB
7G
90G
```

as you can see there is no pattern in these numbers except I have a one or two digits number and letter `G` or `GB` after them.

What query can detect the numbers and delete the characters after that?

Thanks

Comment: Please make an attempt.

Comment: I did actually, before i post my question here i googled it, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

Comment: but still i couldn't figure out a way to detect characters and separate numbers from them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL select query to remove non-numeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/t-sql-select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
drop table #t
create table #t(id varchar(10))
insert into #t values('2GB'), 
            ('3G'),
            ('28GB'),
            ('7G'),
            ('90G')


            update #t
            set id=substring(id,0,PATINDEX('%[GB]%',id)) from #t
            select * from #t
```

### [See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20755)