# Remove weird characters ( A with hat) from SQL Server varchar column

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Some weird characters are getting stored in one of the table. They seem to be coming from `.csv` feeds so I don't have much control over that.

```
Hello Kitty EssentialÃ‚Â AccessoryÃ‚Â Kit
```

How can I clean it and remove these characters. I am ok doing it at db level or in C#.

**EDIT**

As per the suggestions received in comments. I am also looking into what I can do to correct it at feed level. Here's more info on it.

1. Feeds are from third party.
2. I opened feed in notepad++ and checked the encoding menu I see dot
   in front of 'encode in ansi' so I believe that's the encoding of the
   file
3. And that's how it appears in notepad++ "Hello Kitty
   EssentialÂ AccessoryÂ Kit"
4. One strange thing though. when I search that row in powershel from
   csv file. and it comes up with the row. I don't see these weird
   characters there..

Comment: A wild guess is that the CSV is using custom double quotes (“” instead of "") and that you are not using the same encoding/character set in your database connection, causing them to appear as Ã and Â. Perhaps you could add an encoding parameter to your database connection string to prevent this from happening.

Comment: To be clear, you're wanting to remove these characters completely, rather than just removing the diacritical marks from them?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I am ok with removing these characters completely so it will left me with  'Hello Kitty Essential Accessory Kit'

Comment: What are the weird characters? Maybe you can define it's ascii range from 195 to x or something like that

Comment: Agree with @C.Evenhuis: is some weird encoding problem. I think is a typical case in which solving the problem not at this root will cause troubles later

Comment: @FelicePollano I also agree on fixing the root. But it's actualy seems to be within the feed. Here's what I see in feed as well when I open it in notepad++  'Hello Kitty EssentialÂ AccessoryÂ Kit' . So I don't really can do much about it..

Comment: That looks like you have UTF-8 encoding issue, and you probably should look into the file in which encoding it actually is and what encoding you're using when loading it into the database

Comment: @Ankit So fix it in the feed. Data like this shouldn't get into the database in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `.net` regular expression functions. For example, using `Regex.Replace`:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
```

As there is no support for regular expressions in `SQL Server` you need to create a `SQL CLR` function. More information about the `.net` integration in `SQL Server` can be found here:

- [String Utility Functions Sample](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119(v=sql.110).aspx) - full working examples
- [Stairway  to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)  - still in progress
- [Introduction to SQL Server CLR Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx) - official documentation

---

In your case:

1. Open `Visual Studio` and create `Class Library Project`:

   [image]
2. Then rename the class to `StackOverflow` and paste the following code in its file:

   ```
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Data.SqlTypes;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   public class StackOverflow
   {
       [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, Name = "RegexReplace")]
       public static SqlString Replace(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern, SqlString sqlReplacement)
       {
           string input = (sqlInput.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlInput.Value;
           string pattern = (sqlPattern.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlPattern.Value;
           string replacement = (sqlReplacement.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlReplacement.Value;
           return new SqlString(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now, build the project. Open the `SQL Server Management Studio`. Select your database and replace the path value of the following `FROM` clause to match your `StackOverflow.dll`:

   ```
   CREATE ASSEMBLY [StackOverflow] FROM 'C:\Users\gotqn\Desktop\StackOverflow\StackOverflow\bin\Debug\StackOverflow.dll';
   ```
4. Finally, create the `SQL CLR` function:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StackOverflowRegexReplace] (@input NVARCHAR(MAX),@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @replacement NVARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
   AS EXTERNAL NAME [StackOverflow].[StackOverflow].[Replace]
   GO
   ```

You are ready to use `RegexReplace` `.net` function directly in your `T-SQL` statements:

```
    SELECT [dbo].[StackOverflowRegexReplace] ('Hello Kitty EssentialÃ‚Â AccessoryÃ‚Â Kit', '[^\u0000-\u007F]', '')

    //Hello Kitty Essential Accessory Kit
```

Comment: Accepting this as an answer as perhaps has given me flexibility to implement it at Sql Server or c# level.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for alphabets and numbers only in a string, than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c) can help you out.

In this, Regex is used to replace all characters other than alphabets and numbers.

Comment: not really alphabets & numbers.. I just need to remove these weird looking characters, keeping everything else..

Comment: I've already provided links, which are now being posted as answer and not sure why I am being down voted.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. In this case, you should simply cast a close vote - duplicate. Or at most, post this as a comment.

Comment: @Luaan I was not having rights to do so, otherwise I'd definitely have down voted

Comment: @TirthakShah Well, just avoid such questions until you do. There's a plenty of questions (and answerers) around here, there's nothing wrong with skipping over those that you can't answer / downvote / close properly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
string input = "Hello Kitty EssentialÃ‚Â AccessoryÃ‚Â Kit";
string res = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "");

Console.WriteLine(res); // Hello Kitty Essential Accessory Kit
```

Comment: a little too eager IMHO, you remove .,; that can be in the field as well. By a general point of view it could even be possible that sometimes an Â would be actual part of the field... the problem has to be solved CSV side IMHO

Comment: @w.b can you modify your answer to include .;: please. That should serve me as an answer then..

Comment: infact to include all characters we se on a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!,Ã,Â]%'
      SET @str = 'Hello Kitty EssentialÃ‚Â AccessoryÃ‚Â Kit'
      WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
          SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

      SELECT @str
```

Just add any special char you want to get rid off in @expres variable.

Hope this helps!