# how to match substring alphanumric digits and characters, while ignoring hypens, spaces etc

Tags: regex, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

**Data in the DB:** Various users are putting data into my application (as a string from different areas), this data is stored in `[SerialID#] DB column`. Contents are for e.g. barcode numbers, serial numbers etc.

**Edit**: Datasearched, Later another user returns and searches for the same product, but enter his search sub/string with/out the chars.

While doing my search `user entered string` against the `[SerialID#] DB column`, I need the alphanumeric content to match. (by stripping out the additional chars in between in *both* the DB/target and the user string/source).

I have to do this because, some vendors A's serial is different from Vendor B's serial I am unable to control how the user puts data into my app.

I need help in searching the string for only the following two scenarios both in SQL server and on the .NET serverside.

For e.g
`B ABCLKSAL1930239923-938 2998/84`  == Match `ABClksAL1930239923938299884`

Given a source and target string like a barcode/serial with dashes/hyphen;

1. **How can I match the contents alone, ignoring the hypens, slashes, spaces `-` `/ \` or** ?
2. How can I match numbers only? (i.e. digits only)
3. How can I match the contents after the 3 characters
   BMS8937-932093  ==  8937932093
4. would be nice if this can this be parametrized to a function where it can be reused, *[with passing, a) number of first or last characters to ignore b) match digits only vs alphanumberic only  c) specificy the length to truncate]*

I tried this `[A-Za-z0-9]` but was not able to figure out how to match the contents per 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354 to implement regular expressions  support in `T-SQL` using `.net`. Basically, you can create such function in `.net` and use it both in `C#` and `T-SQL` code. As there is not build-in support for regex in `T-SQL` I believe this is the way to go. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: A regex can't match discontinuous text, you might consider a kind of a replace function. Still, to use a real regex, not wildcard patterns, in TSQL, you'd need a UDF.

Comment: I don't suppose it's a option to change your app to write two values (in two separate columns): the original string entered, and a second string matching 1. above?

Comment: I am sorry @stribizhev it is only one string, I should really clarify my question more, after I re read it this morning.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson sorry I am not sure I fully understand your suggestion. The second value is already in the DB, user is typing to search. Now, if I tried to do a separate column per serial by brand I would end up with too many.

Comment: @gotqn thats a really good sample, i am going to try an build on that, which is faster the CLR ver or regex?

Comment: @everest The idea is to use .net code in T-SQL statements. In the example, I am creating regexreplace function, but you can check the links for more examples. You can create your own functions on .net and deploy them to the SQL Server instance.

Comment: @everest I was suggesting having a stored version of the contents in the database that is a 'stripped' form, as a pre-processing step (I suppose you could do this with a computed column), and then using the guaranteed simplified column in your compares.

Comment: both suggestions work, how can I mark them as answers?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) to implement regular expressions  support in `T-SQL` using `.net`. Basically, you can create such function in `.net` and use it both in `C#` and `T-SQL` code. As there is not build-in support for regex in `T-SQL` I believe this is the way to go. Let me know if you have any issues.
The idea is to use .net code in T-SQL statements. In the example, I am creating regexreplace function, but you can check the links for more examples. You can create your own functions on .net and deploy them to the SQL Server instance. – gotqn

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose it's a option to change your app to write two values (in two separate columns): the original string entered, and a second string matching 1. above?
I was suggesting having a stored version of the contents in the database that is a 'stripped' form, as a pre-processing step (I suppose you could do this with a computed column), and then using the guaranteed simplified column in your compares. – Christopher Stevenson