# SQL - Dynamic SQL query to convert single column string delimited with semicolon (;) to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Dynamic SQL query to convert single column string delimited with semicolon (;) to multiple columns.

```
ID           Rollcode            Rack
AA0001   99203; S9088        1350; 1350
ABB0001  99203; S9088        4123; 4123
ADA000   99203; S9088        530; 530
ADM000   99202; S9088;J2308  4516; 4516
ABD000   99203; S9088        3025; 3025

Desired Result should be:

ID    Rollcode1 Rollcode2 Rollcode3 Rack1   Rack2
AA0001  99203   S9088      Null     1350    1350
ABB0001 99203   S9088      Null     4123    4123
ADA000  99203   S9088      Null     530     530
ADM000  99202   S9088     J2308     4516    4516
ABD000  99203   S9088      Null     3025    3025
```

I have tried for 1 column i.e. (Roll Code) can we make it for other columns

```
enter code here DECLARE @pivot varchar(8000) 
DECLARE @select varchar(8000) 
SELECT @pivot=coalesce(@pivot+',','')'[Rollcode'+cast`
(number+1 as varchar(10))+']'
FROM master..spt_values where type='p' and 
number<=(SELECT max(len(Rollcode)-len(replace
(Rollcode,';',''))) FROM tablename) 
SELECT @select=' select p.* 
from ( select  ID,substring(Rollcode, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token, 
''Rollcode''+cast(row_number() over(partition by ID order by start) as 
varchar(10)) as n 
 from ( select ID, Rollcode, n as start
            , charindex('';'',Rollcode,n+2) endPos 
  from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type=''p'') num 
  cross join  
  ( 
  select  
  ID, '';'' + Rollcode +'';'' as Rollcode  
  from  tablename 
  ) m 
  where n < len(Rollcode)-1 
  and substring(Rollcode,n+1,1) = '';'') as Rollcode 
  ) pvt 
  Pivot ( max(token)for n in ('+@pivot+'))p'
  EXEC(@select)
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried

Comment: I have dynamic query which converts only one column (RollCode) but I need other column (RACK) as well

Comment: You are taking denormalized data and transforming into more denormalised data, how do you actually plan on working with this 'dynamic' data?

Comment: If your number of entries is variable, or maybe unknown I would advise to pu them in a separate (links) table (according to your example you should use many to many relation) and connect them using [junction tables](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Comment: @Kris I have a table with unstructured form i.e. have so many duplicates in ID column so I have made distinct by transposing data into rows to columns, so I got distinct ID with respective columns which is delimited by (;) finally I'm converting single column string with delimiter to multiple columns

Comment: My concern is consuming the data in it's final form. I can't think of any presentation or reporting tools that could consume that data. I feel you're possibly unnecessarily complicating the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
declare @roll table (ID nvarchar(20),RollCode nvarchar(100),Rack Nvarchar(100))

insert into @roll
              select 'AA0001'   ,'99203; S9088'         ,'1350; 1350'
union all select 'ABB0001'  ,'99203; S9088'         ,'4123; 4123'
union all select 'ADA000'   ,'99203; S9088'         ,'530; 530'
union all select 'ADM000'   ,'99202; S9088;J2308'   ,'4516; 4516'
union all select 'ABD000'   ,'99203; S9088'         ,'3025; 3025'


 select ID, 
    PARSENAME(replace(RollCode,';','.'),1) as 'RollCode3', 
    PARSENAME(replace(RollCode,';','.'),2) as 'RollCode2',
    PARSENAME(replace(RollCode,';','.'),3) as 'RollCode1',
    PARSENAME(replace(Rack,';','.'),1) as 'Rack2',
    PARSENAME(replace(Rack,';','.'),2) as 'Rack1'

from @roll
```

Comment: @Shaji: In Rollcode column I have so many codes separated with delimiter, instead of using parse name assigning each with column name, using dynamic query can we convert them to multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a way to split the values separated with semi colons. There are various of split functions (some written in pure `T-SQL` and some in `.net`).

I am using a `CLR` function to solve your issue. It's named `[dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexSplitWithOrder]` and splits values by regex pattern. Here is the `.net` code:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRowForSplitWithOrder")]
public static IEnumerable SplitWithOrder(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern)
{
    string[] substrings;
    List<Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>> values = new List<Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>>(); ;

    if (sqlInput.IsNull || sqlPattern.IsNull)
    {
        substrings = new string[0];
    }
    else
    {
        substrings = Regex.Split(sqlInput.Value, sqlPattern.Value);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < substrings.Length; index++)
    {
        values.Add(new Tuple<SqlInt64, SqlString>(new SqlInt64(index), new SqlString(substrings[index])));
    }

    return values;
}
```

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) in order to learn how `CLR` functions are deployed. You can implement pure `T-SQL` function for splitting if you want.

Now, we have a function to split the data (and we need to store it):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[RollCode] VARCHAR(MAX)
   ,[Rack] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [RollCode], [Rack])
VALUES ('AA0001', '99203; S9088', '1350; 1350')
      ,('ABB0001', '99203; S9088', '4123; 4123')
      ,('ADA000', '99203; S9088', '530; 530')
      ,('ADM000', '99202; S9088;J2308', '4516; 4516')
      ,('ABD000', '99203; S9088', '3025; 3025');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDataSource') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempDataSource;
END;

CREATE TABLE #TempDataSource
(
    [ID] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Type] VARCHAR(8)
   ,[Index] INT
   ,[Value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO #TempDataSource ([ID], [Type], [Index], [Value])
SELECT DS.[ID]
      ,'Rollcode'
      ,RS.[index]
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(RS.[value]))
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexSplitWithOrder] (DS.[RollCode], ';') RS
UNION ALL
SELECT DS.[ID]
      ,'Rack'
      ,RS.[index]
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(RS.[value]))
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexSplitWithOrder] (DS.[Rack], ';') RS
```

In the table you have:

[image]

and we are now ready for dynamic `PIVOT`. Note, I am ordering the columns like you want but you can change how the `[ColumnOrder]` is calculated:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',[' + [ColumnName] + ']'
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT([Type], [Index])
                  ,[Index] + IIF([Type] = 'RACK', 100000, 0)
            FROM #TempDataSource
        ) DS ([ColumnName], [ColumnOrder])
        ORDER BY [ColumnOrder]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
   ,1
   ,1
   ,''
);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement =
'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,CONCAT([Type], [Index])
          ,[Value]
    FROM #TempDataSource
) DS ([ID], [ColumnName], [Value])
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR [ColumnName] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT
';

EXEC  sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

The last part gives you:

[image]

It may looks complicated, but it is not. It's trivial dynamic `PIVOT` task. Just implement function for splitting the values and you are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Hint try this,

```
SELECT LEFT(RoleCode,CHARINDEX(';',RoleCode)-1) AS RoleCode1,
       RIGHT(RoleCode,CHARINDEX(';',RoleCode)) AS RoleCode2
FROM tableName
```

Comment: In Rollcode column I have so many codes separated with delimiter, looking for dynamic query which converts to multiple columns