# SQL How to search text field for 2nd without matching 22nd, etc?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query for numbered street names that can occur anywhere within a text column, and filter out matches for numbered street names with more digits, i.e. `2nd` but not `42nd`, `182nd`, etc. Is there any method more graceful or simplified than combination of:

```
WHERE col LIKE '2nd%' OR col LIKE '% 2nd%'
```

Comment: FYI, There is a space character after the first % in the second parameter.

Comment: What is wrong with only - where Adress like '2nd%' ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542022/how-to-use-like-and-in-operator-at-the-same-like-name-like-in-alex-raj/34543158#34543158

Comment: @SpikeEikenbery . . . Your query is using SQL Server syntax conventions (which are standard).  I removed the MS Access tag.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `2nd` doesn't occur at the beginning of the string, you can just check that the character before it is not a digit using

```
col LIKE '%[^0-9]2nd%'
```

For example:

```
select col, case when  col like '%[^0-9]2nd%' then 'second' else 'not' end as test
from (values ('12 2nd st'), ('45 42nd st'), ('128 22nd st')) test(col)
```

Output:

```
col             test
12 2nd st       second
45 42nd st      not
128 22nd st     not
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer is very good, but it doesn't handle the case when `'2nd'` appears at the beginning of a string.  This is easily handled by pre-pending a character on the column being compared:

```
' ' + col LIKE '%[^0-9]2nd%'
```