# Want to add regex in SQL Server check constraints to input only characters not any number even not include any number in character

Tags: sql-server, regex, constraints

I want to add a regex to a SQL Server `check` constraint to input only characters not any number even not include any number in character. Actually I want to input only [a-zA-Z] without mixing or including any numbers.

Please help anybody to provide that regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543158/1080354

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `CHECK` constraint that verifies there are no non-alphabetic characters using:

```
CHECK (col NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')
```

This constraint will fail for any value that has a character in it that is not a letter.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76c05a09d0b03e2d32ec820edbd05eca)

Note that your column/table/database collation may be case-insensitive (e.g. `latin1_swedish_ci`) in which case you can get away with

```
CHECK (col NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%')
```

Comment: Side note for future visitors too; the collation affects whether like is case sensitive. Most SQL server default collations could get away with just `[^A-Z]` to match a-z too

Comment: @CaiusJard good point. I'll add a note about that in the answer.

Comment: @HefajUddin You should accept the answer see how at - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work