# Define Range in SQL Query using Regular Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following values

```
ABCD_AB_1234
ABCD_ABC_2345
ABCD_ABCD_5678
```

and a regular expression to match them

```
ABCD_[A-Z]{2-4}_[0-9]{4}
```

Now I am looking to convert that regular expression to a SQL query so I can get those records back from the database.

Right now I have following where clause

```
where [columnName] like 'ABCD_[A-Z][A-Z]%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

The problem is that I cannot define a range in the SQL query as I did in the regular expression, like {2-4}, what I am doing now is to set the minimum range only.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't confuse pattern matching for full regex, SQL Server does not (natively) support it.

Comment: How did you get on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543158/1080354

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are explaining the full picture the easiest way is probably to create 3 conditions to cover your scenarios e.g.

```
where [columnName] like 'ABCD_[A-Z][A-Z][_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
   or [columnName] like 'ABCD_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
   or [columnName] like 'ABCD_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Its not optimal but SQL Server doesn't have any regex support so if you have to do it in SQL this is one way.