# Stuffing data of one column when data in all other column same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to concatenate value present in `params` and `Note` separated by semicolon whenever data in other column same.

**when data in a column AppID ,FileID Action ,ID ,BaseVehicleID ,ParttypeID ,SubModelID are same then only concatenate the params and note
else not, and display it as individual record in output.**

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
AppID INT,  
FileID INT,
Action CHAR (1),    
ID INT, 
BaseVehicleID INT,  
ParttypeID INT, 
SubModelID INT, 
Params VARCHAR (50),    
Note VARCHAR (50)
)
INSERT @TABLE

SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5560,'' ,   'check1',   'M14 x 1.50 Thread' UNION ALL

SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5560,'' ,   'check2',   'Package Quantity: 5'  UNION ALL

SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5569,'',        ''  ,'Dorman - AutoGrade - Boxed'
```

Expected Output

```
 2  1   A   2   4935    5560    0   check1;check2   M14 x 1.50 Thread;Package Quantity: 5

 2  1   A   2   4935    5569    0                  Dorman - AutoGrade - Boxed
```

Comment: This isn't particularly easy to do in SQL Server.  Furthermore, this is essentially denormalizing your database table.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: my records count are huge in millions and, except params and note, values in other column are same 
so i am trying to reduced the record count, stuffing params and note when value in all other column same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
;WITH DataSource AS
(
    -- columns on which we are grouping
    SELECT DISTINCT [AppID]
                   ,[FileID]
                   ,[Action]
                   ,[ID]
                   ,[BaseVehicleID]
                   ,[ParttypeID]
                   ,[SubModelID]
    FROM @TABLE
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
      (
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT ';' +[Params]
            FROM @TABLE T
            WHERE T.[AppID] = DS.[AppID]
                AND T.[FileID] = DS.[FileID]
                AND T.[Action] = DS.[Action]
                AND T.[ID] = T.[ID]
                AND T.[BaseVehicleID] = DS.[BaseVehicleID]
                AND T.[ParttypeID] = DS.[ParttypeID]
                AND T.[SubModelID] = DS.[SubModelID]
                AND [Params] <> ''
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
          ,1
          ,1
          ,''
       )

) DS1([Params])
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
      (
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT ';' +[Note]
            FROM @TABLE T
            WHERE T.[AppID] = DS.[AppID]
                AND T.[FileID] = DS.[FileID]
                AND T.[Action] = DS.[Action]
                AND T.[ID] = T.[ID]
                AND T.[BaseVehicleID] = DS.[BaseVehicleID]
                AND T.[ParttypeID] = DS.[ParttypeID]
                AND T.[SubModelID] = DS.[SubModelID]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
          ,1
          ,1
          ,''
       )
) DS2 ([Note])
```

[image]

Note, that this can become even more complex if you have many columns to group by. There are not T-SQL native implementation for aggregate concatenation function, but you can implement such if you want using `SQL CLR`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692940/remove-weird-characters-a-with-hat-from-sql-server-varchar-column/31693412#31693412) contains everything you need. If you implement such function, the solution will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
> (
> AppID INT,  FileID INT,Action CHAR (1),    ID INT, BaseVehicleID INT,  ParttypeID INT, SubModelID INT, Params VARCHAR (50),    
> Note VARCHAR (50))
>
> INSERT @TABLE
>
> SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5560,'' ,   'check1',   'M14 x 1.50 Thread' UNION ALl
> SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5560,'' ,   'check2',   'Package Quantity: 5'  UNION ALl
> SELECT 2,   1,  'A',    2,  4935,   5560,'',        ''  ,'Dorman - AutoGrade - Boxed' 
>
> select *from @table
>
>
>
> select AppID, FileID, [Action],ID, BaseVehicleID, ParttypeID, SubModelID,
> STUFF(
>            (SELECT ';' + Params
>            from @TABLE
>            group by AppID, FileID, [Action],ID, BaseVehicleID, ParttypeID, SubModelID,Params
>            FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS Params,
>            STUFF(
>            (SELECT ';' + Note
>            from @TABLE
>            group by AppID, FileID, [Action],ID, BaseVehicleID, ParttypeID, SubModelID,Note
>            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Note
>
> from @table 
> group by AppID, FileID, [Action],ID, BaseVehicleID, ParttypeID, SubModelID
> ```