# String split/chunks into chunked columns from one varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, relational-database

Hopefully everyone is having a productive lockdown all over the world. This is my second issue I wanted some assistance with today.

What I have is a chat from a telecom company signing up new customers.
I have successfully collapsed them into 2x rows per unique_id - a unique chat interaction captured between customer and company agent.

- I would like to now take each column (text) in each row and separate
  it out to 5 equal varchar columns.
- The objective is to splice/chunk a
  conversation into 5 different stages within this table.
- I do not
  have access to delimiters as customers and company staff use
  delimiting characters themselves so it makes this tricky.

Below I have 2 images with what the data looks like now and what I am looking for.

BEFORE

[image: Current DB image showing text in separate lines]

AFTER

[image: What I would like to see when the text column is divided]

I have looked at the following articles to try to crack it, but am stuck:

- [Split A Single Field Value Into Multiple Fixed-Length Column Values in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079084/split-a-single-field-value-into-multiple-fixed-length-column-values-in-t-sql/38079732#38079732)
- [How to Split String by Character into Separate Columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991953/how-to-split-string-by-character-into-separate-columns-in-sql-server)
- [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)
- [How to split a single column values to multiple column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)
- [Split string in SQL Server to a maximum length, returning each as a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852612/split-string-in-sql-server-to-a-maximum-length-returning-each-as-a-row)

Here is the SQL Fiddle page, but I am running this code in MS SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddd08c

Here is the table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`unique_id` double, `user` varchar(8), `text` varchar(144))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`unique_id`, `user`, `text`)
VALUES
    (50314585222,  'customer', 'This is part 1 of long text. This is part 2 of long text. This is part 3 of long text. This is part 4 of long text. This is part 5 of long text.'),
    (50314585222, 'company', 'This is part 1 of long text This is part 2 of long text This is part 3 of long text This is part 4 of long text This is part 5 of long text'),
    (50319875222,  'customer', 'This is part 1 This is part 2 This is part 3 This is part 4 This is part 5'),
    (50319875222,  'company', 'This is part 1 This is part 2 This is part 3 This is part 4 This is part 5')
;
```

I have requested an almost similar algorithm in R, in my history. I have been trying to do this in SQL.

Comment: Without any form of delimiter how do you decide where to split the text?

Comment: I was hoping to divide it by total length of column / 5, and then somehow make sure that entire word makes it through without cutting out in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to solve this with the `T-SQL` statement below:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,'\b.{1,'+CAST(CEILING(LEN([text]) * 1.0 /5) AS VARCHAR(12)) +'}\b' AS [pattern]
    FROM TAble1
), PreparedData AS
(
    SELECT unique_id
          ,[user]
          ,'text' +  CAST(RM.matchID + 1 AS VARCHAR(12)) as [column]
          ,RM.CaptureValue AS [value]
    FROM DataSource T
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] ([text], [pattern]) RM
)
SELECT *
FROM PreparedData DS
PIVOT
(
    max([value]) for [column] IN ([text1], [text2], [text3], [text4], [text5])
) PVT;
```

[image]

In order to use this code, you need to implement [SQL CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) function(s) for working with regular expression in the context of T-SQL (you need to invest some time understanding how SQL CLR works) - otherwise, you will not be able to use this solution.

So, having `RegexMatches` function, the first part is to build a regular expression pattern for splitting the data:

```
SELECT *
      ,'\b.{1,'+CAST(CEILING(LEN([text]) * 1.0 /5) AS VARCHAR(12)) +'}\b' AS [pattern]
FROM TAble1;
```

The pattern is `\b.number\b` and will match part of the strings with length `number` but not cutting the words (check if boundary works for you, because in some cases it [won't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56964507/1080354)).

Then, using our `regex matches` function we getting a result like this (the second common table expression):

[image]

And the data above is ready for pivoting which is pretty easy.

So, the notes are:

- you need to implement [Microsoft String Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ff878119(v=sql.110))
- you need to ensure the regex pattern works for you
- you can split the T-SQL I used, check the other columns of the regex function and even make dynamic pivoting - the code is an example and need to modify/check it before using in production