# SELECT first 10 words from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need select query for first 10 words from SQL Table Field.

I have field Name: Description, so i need first 10 words from description field.

**EX:** **Description**: I don't feel good about this answer; I don't like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers.  Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this.

**output**:  I don't feel good about this answer; I don't like

Comment: please add expected output,inputs and what have you tried so far

Comment: look here to know more on how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: *What* answers are you talking about? In any case numbers tables make things *faster*. The problem is the question itself - it's extremely vague. In any case, SQL isn't a string manipulation language. It's not whether you like a query or not but whether it produces the results in the most efficient way

Comment: The way this question is written, you may be asking how to split descriptions and pick the first 10 words as a result. Or you may be asking how to extract the first 10 words from each description instead of the full description. Why don't you do that on the *client* anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a CROSS APPLY and a little XML.  The logic in the CROSS APPLY could easily be ported into a UDF (scalar or table-valued).

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,LongDesc varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'I don''t feel good about this answer; I don''t like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers. Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this.')

Select A.ID
      ,ShortDesc = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(100)')+' '
                          +xDim.value('/x[10]','varchar(100)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.LongDesc,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ShortDesc
1   I don't feel good about this answer; I don't like
```

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I'm all about benchmarks and willing to admit when I'm wrong.  However, in this case my approach is faster.  Ran a series benchmark test on 100K records.  5 runs each.  My approach a average of 161 ms.  Your approach 377 ms.

Comment: i should say what tool did you use?

Comment: Remote connection to a client's BIG ASS server.   Similar results on my laptop.   As far as the test, I import/refresh all of the FRED series definitions ... some 579,733 records with an avg note length of 544 characters or 74 words.  My advice it to run your own test and decide what works best for your.  BTW - I digg the debate  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti , your script is hard coded,suppose in another example i want top 15 then i hv to modify your script.I cannot pass parameter

Comment: @KumarHarsh If you want variable, you would have to go vertical, or a UDF

Comment: @KumarHarsh Should have mentioned.  If you want 15, just follow the pattern.  If you want variable then you would have to go vertical

Answer (score 2):

Is the left() function ok?

```
select left(Description, 10) from your_table;
```

Comment: This will return the first 10 characters, not the first 10 words

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) answer in order to learn how to implement and use `.net` functions in the context of `SQL Server`. Here, I am using `SQLSCLR` implementation of the of the `.net` `Regex.Match`function.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Description])
VALUES ('word01, word02,         word03, word04, word05, word06')
      ,('word01,word02, word03, word04, word05, word06')
      ,('word01!word02, word03: word04, word05, word06');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] ([Description], '^(\w+\b.*?){3}') RM;
```

This gives you the following output:

[image]

which is too detailed (and extraging only the first `three` words). Your final query can be something like this:

```
SELECT DS.[Description], RM.[CaptureValue]
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] ([Description], '^(?n)(\w+\b.*?){3}') RM;
```

[image]

Anyway, using regex you can use the any separators you want, but the more important thing is you can execute `.net` code in the context of `T-SQL` which is huge.

You have a lot of to read and learn from here. The previous answer is more easy and faster to be implemented.

Comment: Huge in memory consumption and delays as well. Even with the most careful coding a regex will generate a match tree whether you need the results or not. The way these queries are written, it will do so for *all* rows. There is a reason SQLCLR string splitting methods *don't* use regex

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need to test each time your solution in order to be sure it will work as expected with your production data. This is demonstration of SQLCLR only.

Comment: It's a link to a demonstration. If you search for `T-SQL string split` you'll find various SQLCLR implementations. The fastest enumerates over characters directly only as long as needed. It's speed is comparable to SQL Server 2016's STRING_SPLIT. If you only want 10 words out of 100, that's a huge improvement

Comment: A regex would help if it could return everything up to the 10th occurence of a space, or just the index of the 10th space. This wouild be a single match that could be used directly, or as and argument to `LEFT()`. It would probably be faster than `STRING_SPLIT` because it wouldn't generate any substrings

Comment: I think `^(?:[^\s]*\s){10}` would return everything up to and including the 10th whitespace as a single string result

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this

```
declare @message nvarchar(max) = 'I don''t feel good about this answer; I don''t like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers. Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this'

SELECT left(@message,
CHARINDEX(' ', @message,
  CHARINDEX(' ', @message,
    CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
     CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
      CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
       CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
        CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
         CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
          CHARINDEX(' ',@message,
            CHARINDEX(' ',@message) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 )+ 1 ) + 1))
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

try this with big data.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(COL1 NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('I dont feel good about this answer; I dont like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers. Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this.')

;WITH CTE AS
(
select col1,substring(col1,1,CHARINDEX(' ',col1))Words
,substring(col1,CHARINDEX(' ',col1)+1,len(col1))Residue
, 1 rn from @t

union ALL
select col1,substring(Residue,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Residue))
,substring(Residue,CHARINDEX(' ',Residue)+1,len(Residue))
,rn+1
from cte
where len(Words)>0 and rn<10
)
SELECT Words FROM cte
```

Comment: will take 60ms to run

Comment: @maSTArHiAn , i just tested,for 10,000 rows(that means output is 1,00,000 rows ) avg time is 6ms.can you throw sample data

Comment: Execution elapsed time not writing time.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn,  you are right.my script take 6232 ms for 10000 rows.John Cappelletti script takes just 279 ms. I come with other solution soon.But in another example ,Recursive CTE take far less time than xml method.if i get that link,i post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have an answer, but I just wanted to do it in a different way.

```
DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(8000)= 'I don''t feel good about this answer; I don''t like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers. Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this.'
DECLARE @LOOP INT = 1
DECLARE @STR_POS INT = 1
DECLARE @CI INT
DECLARE @RES_STR VARCHAR(8000) = ''

WHILE(@LOOP<=10)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CI = CHARINDEX(' ',@WORD,@STR_POS)
        SELECT @RES_STR = @RES_STR +' '+ SUBSTRING(@WORD,@STR_POS,(CHARINDEX(' ',@WORD,@STR_POS)-@STR_POS))
        SET @STR_POS = @CI+1
        SET @LOOP=@LOOP+1

    END
PRINT @RES_STR
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not give you a row set solution, but another option to parse out the first ten words using a similar technique with less code, purely for illustration.. i suppose this can be converted to a user defined function, but we know they don't perform well. it can probably be combined using CrossApply to eliminate the need for a UDF. I must credit this for help with xml syntax: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/

```
DECLARE 
@xml as xml,
@str as varchar(1000)= 'I don''t feel good about this answer; I don''t like the GROUP BY and I would rather not do the table of numbers. Hopefully somebody can pick me up on this.',
@delimiter as char(1) = char(32),
@xmlspace  as char(13) = '<y>&#160;</y>'

SET @xml = cast(('<x>'+replace(@str,@delimiter,@xmlspace)+'</x>') as xml)

SELECT TOP 10 N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') FROM @xml.nodes('x') as T(N)
```

Comment: this took 43ms to run