# How to Replace After special characters with other column value in same position in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to replace the missing string in between special characters with other column same position special character string in sql? below is the example

Eg :

```
ColumnA                columnB        Output of columnb 
~as~df~gf~er            ~qw~~~          ~qw~df~gf~er
~Evening~Afternoon       ~~             ~Evening~Afternoon
~qw~dg~er~rt~yu~io~ty   ~df~~rt~~we~~   ~df~dg~rt~rt~we~io~ty
```

Note: Both columns special characters count will be same.
I need output in column like this  ~qw~df~gf~er . 

I want change dynamically in all the missing strings in special character.Please help me on this

Comment: wht is ur update rule in <Output of columnb> which is very unclear ?

Comment: in which position the data should be replace or update ?

Comment: Where ever missing string in between special character we need to replace the columnA string in same position.Out of columnb is need to update columnb like this ( am giving sample how I need to update in columnb )

Comment: sequence should be same or random sequence in <Output of columnb > ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the right functions and this can be solve easily. For example, in my database I have:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [ColumnA] VARCHAR(1024)
   ,[ColumnB] VARCHAR(1024)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ColumnA], [ColumnB])
VALUES ('~as~df~gf~er', '~qw~~~')
      ,('~Evening~Afternoon', '~~')
      ,('~qw~dg~er~rt~yu~io~ty', '~df~~rt~~we~~');


SELECT DS.[ColumnA]
      ,DS.[ColumnB]
      ,[dbo].[ConcatenateWithOrderAndDelimiter] (A.[index], ISNULL(NULLIF(B.[value], ''), A.[value]), '~')
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexSplitWithOrder] ([ColumnA], '~') A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [ColumnA]
          ,B.[index]
          ,B.[value]
    FROM @DataSource DS
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexSplitWithOrder] ([ColumnB], '~') B
) B
    ON DS.[ColumnA] = B.[ColumnA]
    AND A.[index] = B.[index]
GROUP BY DS.[ColumnA]
        ,DS.[ColumnB];
```

[image]

So, basically you need two functions:

1. one for splitting strings by value
2. one for string aggregation (concatenation)

In my case I am using SQL CLR function - you can find more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354).

In SQL Server 2017, we can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) and from SQL Server 2016 we can use [STRING_SPIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

If you do not want to waste time for implementing SQL CLR functions, you can add a split function (there are a lot of them in the net). For example, I have used this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Analysis_ConvertCsvListToNVarCharTableWithOrder](@List nvarchar(max), @Delimiter nvarchar(10) = ',')
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(   
    [Value] nvarchar(max),
    [SortOrder] bigint NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Delimiter is null 
    BEGIN
        SET @Delimiter = ','
    END
    DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

    DECLARE @BufTable TABLE (Value nvarchar(max), SortOrder bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY)
    INSERT INTO @BufTable (Value)
        SELECT Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM   @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
        OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@xml = NULL)) 

    INSERT INTO @result (Value, SortOrder)
        SELECT Value, SortOrder
        FROM @BufTable

    RETURN
END
```

And this should will give you want you want:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS.[ColumnA]
          ,DS.[ColumnB]
          ,A.[SortOrder]
          ,ISNULL(NULLIF(B.[value], ''), A.[Value]) AS [Value]
    FROM @DataSource DS
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Analysis_ConvertCsvListToNVarCharTableWithOrder] (REPLACE([ColumnA], ',', '~'), '~') A
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT [ColumnA]
              ,B.[SortOrder]
              ,B.[value]
        FROM @DataSource DS
        CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Analysis_ConvertCsvListToNVarCharTableWithOrder] (REPLACE([ColumnB], ',', '~'), '~') B
    ) B
        ON DS.[ColumnA] = B.[ColumnA]
        AND A.[SortOrder] = B.[SortOrder]
)
SELECT DISTINCT A.[ColumnA]
               ,A.[ColumnB]
               ,DS.[value]
FROM DataSource A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT '~' + B.[Value]
            FROM DataSource B
            WHERE A.[ColumnA]  = B.[ColumnA]
            ORDER BY B.[SortOrder]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS ([value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try without creating `Function()` :-

```
DECLARE @ColumnA NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @columnB NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ColumnA = '~as~df~gf~er ';
SET @columnB = ' ~qw~~~';

;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @ColumnA) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(@ColumnA, '~', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)),
     CTE1
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @columnB) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(@columnB, '~', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a))
     SELECT @ColumnA AS ColumnA,
            @columnB AS columnB,
            [Output of columnb] =
     (
         SELECT '~'+CASE
                        WHEN C1.DATA1 = ''
                        THEN C2.DATA
                        ELSE C1.DATA1
                    END
         FROM CTE1 C1
              INNER JOIN CTE C2 ON C2.RN = C1.RN
                                   AND C1.RN > 1 FOR XML PATH('')
     );
```

**Desired Output :**

```
ColumnA                columnB        Output of columnb 
~as~df~gf~er            ~qw~~~          ~qw~df~gf~er
```