# CLR Assembly invocation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, clr

I have developed a small DLL containing a single function as shown below:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class UWQ_IF_to_Excel

    Public Function Excel_Calculate(ByVal p_File_Reference, ByVal p_Sheet_Reference, ByVal p_In_Cells_Values, ByVal p_Result_Cell, ByRef p_Result, ByRef p_Result_Code)

        <body>

        Return 0

    End Function


End Class
```

Out DBA loaded it with the name `xsp_excel`.

From the documentation I learned that I need to create a function referencing the assembly, but I keep getting syntax errors even though I'm following the instructions in [here](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/March-2013/CLR-Functions-in-SQL-Server-A-Tutorial).

Could anyone post the right way of doing it?

*(NOTE: I'm aware that SQL SERVER does not allow OUT parameters in function (in contrast to other DBMSs), but at this point I want to reach the point in which the function is invoked; once this is working, will change the DLL to return a table like in the example of the link above)*.

### Edit

Based on the example provided gotqn (see comment below), I'm trying this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UWQ].[p_FUND_Calculate_With_Excel] ( @_l_Excel_File              NVARCHAR(512)        ,
                                                       @_l_Excel_Sheet             NVARCHAR( 64)        ,
                                                       @_l_Excel_String_to_Send    NVARCHAR(999)        ,
                                                       @_l_Excel_Result_Cell       NVARCHAR( 16)        ,
                                                       @_l_Result                  FLOAT         OUTPUT ,
                                                       @_l_Result_Code             INT           OUTPUT   )

AS EXTERNAL NAME [dbo].[xsp_excel].[UWQ_IF_to_Excel].[Excel_Calculate] ;
```

As far as I can see, the syntax appears to be correct (obviously I'm missing something though). Still, I'm getting the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure p_FUND_Calculate_With_Excel, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

When double-clicking at the error, the cursor is moved to the line `AS EXTERNAL NAME [dbo].[xsp_excel].[UWQ_IF_to_Excel].[Excel_Calculate] ;`.

Can anyone tell me what the error is?

Comment: can you try this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354

Comment: @gotqn, please check the **EDIT**. Still cannot get what I want. Thanks!!!!