# Regex for PostgreSQL for getting domain with sub-domain from URL/Website

Tags: regex, postgresql

Basically, I need to get those rows which contain domain and subdomain name from a URL or the whole website name excluding `www`.

My DB table looks like this:

```
+----------+------------------------+
|    id    |    website             |
+----------+------------------------+
| 1        | https://www.google.com |
+----------+------------------------+
| 2        | http://www.google.co.in|
+----------+------------------------+
| 3        | www.google.com         |
+----------+------------------------+
| 4        | www.google.co.in       |
+----------+------------------------+
| 5        | google.com             |
+----------+------------------------+
| 6        | google.co.in           |
+----------+------------------------+
| 7        | http://google.co.in    |
+----------+------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
google.com
google.co.in
google.com
google.co.in
google.com
google.co.in
google.co.in
```

My Postgres Query looks like this:

```
select id, substring(website from '.*://([^/]*)') as website_domain from contacts
```

But above query give blank websites. So, how I can get the desired output?

Comment: `google.com` has no subdomain AFAIK...so why does it appear in your expected output?

Comment: blank websites?.. for which row?..

Comment: Basically, I want the whole website after ```www.```

Comment: but in some cases website doesn't contain ```www.``` then I need the whole thing like ```google.com``` or ```google.co.in```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(website, '^(https?://)?(www\.)?', '') from tbl;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUphot/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(https?://)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `http://` or `https://`
- `(www\.)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `www.`

See the [PostgreSQL demo](http://rextester.com/JZRZK86441):

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
    (website character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tb1
    (website)
VALUES
    ('https://www.google.com'),
    ('http://www.google.co.in'),
    ('www.google.com'),
    ('www.google.co.in'),
    ('google.com'),
    ('google.co.in'),
    ('http://google.co.in')
;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(website, '^(https?://)?(www\.)?', '') from tb1;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This also works for me. One more thing my friend and me working on the same project but due to C# he is using SQLite(MySQL). So Can you also help me because REGEXP_REPLACE is not supporting MySQL

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava In C#, with MS SQL, you need to use an UDF to be able to use regex. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/3832970) that should help to get started. Also, you might want to use [this script](https://sqlsharp.com/free/).

Answer (score 22):

You must use the "non capturing" match `?:` to cope with the non "http://" websites.

like

```
select 
  id, 
  substring(website from '(?:.*://)?(?:www\.)?([^/?]*)') as website_domain     
from contacts;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f890c/2/0

PostgreSQL's regular expressions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE

Comment: In this case, the website contains ```www.``` need to remove this also

Comment: The www is an extand of this technique, i've update the answer

Comment: which is good technique ```substring ``` or ```REGEX_REPLACE```(as in above ans) because the query need to be optimize because this query works on large amount of data