# Rails - Filter by domain of the URL PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one table pages which has `url` field. I want to filter those records by domain name.
Below are the sample domains from list of URL.

- http://test.host
- http://localhost:3000
- https://www.testing.staging.io
- https://staging.example.com

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528966/regex-for-postgresql-for-getting-domain-with-sub-domain-from-url-website) answer. But REGEXP_REPLACE is not working in where condition.

Below is the query that I tried but it is only allowing to filter by hostname, I want regex which work for the domain name.

```
Page.where("substring(url from '.*://([^/]*)') in (?)", ['test.host'])
```

The request parameter for domains will be ['http://test.host'] not ['test.host'].

I am looking for the best solution to tackle this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173734/extracting-top-level-and-second-level-domain-from-a-url-using-regex

Comment: @max I think you didn't get my question. I want a full domain with the scheme. Currently what i missing is scheme part and above question is not matching anywhere.