# How to replace substring in a column using lookup table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, lookup-tables

I have one table which has two columns with data code points like . These code points need to be changed with japanese characters. I have a lookup table of these code points with the japanese characters. But the problem is in both of the columns there are multiple code points in single rows.

Main table:-

```
Id    body                                      subject
1    <U+9876> Hi <U+1234>No <U+6543>           <U+9876> Hi <U+1234>No <U+6543>
2    <U+9826> <U+5678><U+FA32> data            <U+9006> <U+6502>
```

Lookup table :-

```
char     value
<U+9876>  だ
<U+9826>  づ
```

I tried creating an update query with like operator in inner join but it is taking lot of time as we have 14k rows in main table and 6K values in lookup tables.

Comment: Maybe you should not implement this in SQL. 14K+6K is not too big amount of data, you can load it all into objects inside your application. Lookup table should be loaded into some hashmap, so you can have very fast access to its elements. Then you can process main table in a loop. I believe it can be faster then pure sql solution, and I am very curious about your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the performance really matters you need to materialized the data in advanced. This can be done creating separate table and using a trigger or modifying the routine that is populating the original table. If you are records are not inserted/updated on batches you will not harm the CRUD execution time.

You can easy create a good looking short T-SQL statement for building dynamic code for performing 6K updates, so you can give this a shot, too - don't use `LIKE` or complex conditions - just simple `UPDATE-REPLACE` statements for each lookup value.

In some cases, I am using SQL CLR functions for such replaces. For example:

```
DECLARE @Main TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[body] NVARCHAR(MAX)
   ,[subject] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @Lookup TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT -- you can use row_number to order
   ,[char] NVARCHAR(32)
   ,[value] NVARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @Main ([id], [body], [subject])
VALUES (1, '<U+9876> Hi <U+1234>No <U+6543>', '<U+9876> Hi <U+1234>No <U+6543>')
      ,(2, '<U+9826> <U+5678><U+FA32> data', '<U+9006> <U+6502>');

INSERT INTO @Lookup ([id], [char], [value])
VALUES (1, '<U+9876>', N'だ')
      ,(2, '<U+9826>', N'づ');

DECLARE @Pattern NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@Replacement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Pattern = [dbo].[ConcatenateWithOrderAndDelimiter] ([id], [char], '|')
      ,@Replacement = [dbo].[ConcatenateWithOrderAndDelimiter] ([id], [value], '|')
FROM @Lookup;


UPDATE @Main
SET [body] = [dbo].[fn_Utils_ReplaceStrings] ([body], @Pattern, @Replacement, '|')
   ,[subject] = [dbo].[fn_Utils_ReplaceStrings] ([subject], @Pattern, @Replacement, '|');

 SELECT [id]
       ,[body]
       ,[subject]
 FROM @Main;
```

[image]

I am showing you the code behind below, but this is just an idea. You are free to implement something on your own, which satisfy your performance requirements.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354), you can see how SQL CLR function is created. Here, is a variant of aggregate function concatenating with order:

```
[Serializable]
[
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate
    (
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.Format.UserDefined,
        IsInvariantToNulls = true,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
        IsInvariantToOrder = false,
        IsNullIfEmpty = false,
        MaxByteSize = -1
    )
]
/// <summary>
/// Concatenates <int, string, string> values defining order using the specified number and using the given delimiter
/// </summary>
public class ConcatenateWithOrderAndDelimiter : Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize
{
    private List<Tuple<int, string>> intermediateResult;
    private string delimiter;
    private bool isDelimiterNotDefined;

    public void Init()
    {
        this.delimiter = ",";
        this.isDelimiterNotDefined = true;
        this.intermediateResult = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlInt32 position, SqlString text, SqlString delimiter)
    {
        if (this.isDelimiterNotDefined)
        {
            this.delimiter = delimiter.IsNull ? "," : delimiter.Value;
            this.isDelimiterNotDefined = false;
        }

        if (!(position.IsNull || text.IsNull))
        {
            this.intermediateResult.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(position.Value, text.Value));
        }
    }

    public void Merge(ConcatenateWithOrderAndDelimiter other)
    {
        this.intermediateResult.AddRange(other.intermediateResult);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        this.intermediateResult.Sort();
        return new SqlString(String.Join(this.delimiter, this.intermediateResult.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2)));
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        if (r == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("r");

        int count = r.ReadInt32();
        this.intermediateResult = new List<Tuple<int, string>>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.intermediateResult.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(r.ReadInt32(), r.ReadString()));
        }

        this.delimiter = r.ReadString();
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        if (w == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("w");

        w.Write(this.intermediateResult.Count);
        foreach (Tuple<int, string> record in this.intermediateResult)
        {
            w.Write(record.Item1);
            w.Write(record.Item2);
        }
        w.Write(this.delimiter);
    }
}
```

Here is one variant of function performing replacement:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString ReplaceStrings( SqlString input, SqlString pattern, SqlString replacement, SqlString separator ){
    string output = null;
    if(
        input.IsNull == false
        && pattern.IsNull == false
        && replacement.IsNull == false
    ){
        StringBuilder tempBuilder = new StringBuilder( input.Value );

        if( separator.IsNull || String.IsNullOrEmpty( separator.Value ) ){
            tempBuilder.Replace( pattern.Value, replacement.Value );
        }
        else{
            //both must have the exact number of elements
            string[] vals = pattern.Value.Split( new[]{separator.Value}, StringSplitOptions.None ),
                newVals = replacement.Value.Split( new[]{separator.Value}, StringSplitOptions.None );

            for( int index = 0, count = vals.Length; index < count; index++ ){
                tempBuilder.Replace( vals[ index ], newVals[ index ] );
            }
        }

        output = tempBuilder.ToString();
    }

    return output;
}
```

or this one but using regex:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, Name = "RegexReplaceStrings")]
public static SqlString ReplaceStrings(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern, SqlString sqlReplacement, SqlString sqlSeparator)
{
    string returnValue = "";

    // if any of the input parameters is "NULL" no replacement is performed at all
    if (sqlInput.IsNull || sqlPattern.IsNull || sqlReplacement.IsNull || sqlSeparator.IsNull)
    {
        returnValue = sqlInput.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        string[] patterns = sqlPattern.Value.Split(new string[] {sqlSeparator.Value}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] replacements = sqlReplacement.Value.Split(new string[] { sqlSeparator.Value }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // The map structure is populated with all values from the "patterns" array as if no corresponding value exists
        // in the "replacements" array the current value from the "pattern" array is used a a replacement value. The
        // result is no replacement is done in the "sqlInput" string if the given "pattern" is matched.
        for (int index = 0; index < patterns.Length; index++)
        {
            map[patterns[index]] = index < replacements.Length ? replacements[index] : patterns[index];
        }

        returnValue = Regex.Replace(sqlInput.Value, String.Join("|", patterns.Select(patern => Regex.Replace(patern, @"\(|\)|\||\.", @"\$&")).OrderByDescending(patern => patern.Length).ToArray()), match =>
        {
            string currentValue;

            if (!map.TryGetValue(match.Value, out currentValue))
            {
                currentValue = match.Value;
            }

            return currentValue; 
        });
    }

    return new SqlString(returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function that loops through any text replacing its code points.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DecodeString( @STRING nvarchar(1000) )
RETURNS nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @POS int
  DECLARE @CODE nvarchar(20)

  SET @POS = CHARINDEX('<', @STRING);
  WHILE @POS > 0 BEGIN
    SET @CODE = SUBSTRING(@STRING, @POST , CHARINDEX('>', @STRING) - @POS + 1);

    SELECT @STRING = REPLACE(@STRING, @CODE, VALUE)
    FROM MYLOOKUPTABLE 
    WHERE CHAR = @CODE;

    SET @POS = CHARINDEX('<', @STRING);
  END

  RETURN @STRING;
END
GO
```

Now you can use that function to get or update the resulting strings, and it will only lookup for just the needed keys on each string.

```
SELECT Body, DecodeString(Body) as JapaneseBody,
       Subject, DecodeString(Subject) as JapaneseSubject
FROM MYTABLE
```

Just remember to have an index on the "char" column at the lookup table, so those searches will be optimal.