# How to generate a create table for the result of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have several Stored Prodedures with many many columns.
For each of them I need to put the result of the SProc in a temp table, therefore I have to first declare these tables. This is a tedious work that I'd like to automate.
Is it possible, given the name of a SProc, to obtain the script of a table that can contain the result of the SProc?
I Would try with "sp_describe_first_result_set" BUT several of my SProcs have their only result set generated via DynamicSQL (that's the reason for the many columns...) and it seems "sp_describe_first_result_set" is not working in that case (unsurprisingly)

Thank you

Comment: That's the main reason, why I try to avoid SPs for *reading* data... If you are open to a non-sql-server solution you might use C# to fill a generic `System.Data.DataTable` directly from a SP. The table's metadata will then provide all you need to create a fitting table. You might create a tiny external tool for this...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fight the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) of `sp_decribe_first_result_set` in any way. I have spent a lot of time (and continue spending some each couple of mounts) and the result is we need to learn to live with them.

As to your question, I have also stored procedure which is generating different `T-SQL` dynamic statements depending on its parameters. And like you, I need to store its result set sometimes (and we need to define the structure of the temporary table before storing the data).

In order to improve this, I've added a mode, which is describing the result set, instead of returning the data. Its something like this:

```
IF [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexIsMatch] ('(?i)\[DescribeFirstResultSet]', @MiscSettings) = 1
    BEGIN;
        SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexReplace] (@DynamicTSQLStatement, 'CREATE TABLE #([^\s]+)', 'DECLARE @$1 TABLE');
        SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = REPLACE(@DynamicTSQLStatement, '#', '@');
        SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexReplace] (@DynamicTSQLStatement, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.+?;', '');

        SELECT [column_ordinal]
              ,REPLACE([name], '@', '#') AS [name]
              ,[system_type_name]
              ,IIF([column_ordinal] = 1, '', ',') + '[' + REPLACE([name], '@', '#') + '] ' + UPPER([system_type_name]) AS [column_definition]
        FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set] (@DynamicTSQLStatement, NULL, 0); 

        EXEC [sys].[sp_describe_first_result_set] @DynamicTSQLStatement;

        RETURN;
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN;
        EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
    END;
```

So, in my case, the developer is setting the columns ze needs in a parameter but is calling the stored procedure with the description option. So, the result is like this:

[image]

Few notes:

- you can try to use the definition in order to create a temporary table and then in dynamic T-SQL statement to execute your stored procedure
- note, that I am replacing/converting my temporary tables to table variables (this is needed due limitations again)
- if you want to use CLR `regex replace` function check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354)