# Extract Numbers out of String wherever it appears

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the below samples, how could you extract the numbers out as SourceID and DestinationID given "Status changed from X to X" can appear anywhere in the text?

```
Create Table #temp
(
    LogValue varchar(100)
)

insert into #temp
(
    LogValue
)
select
    'Status changed from 1 to 10' --SourceID = 1, DestinationID = 10
union all
select
    'Mary had a little lamb Status changed from 4 to 12'--SourceID = 4, DestinationID = 12
union all
select
    'Mary had a little lamb Status changed from 5 to 17 Its fleece was white as snow,' --SourceID = 5, DestinationID = 17
union all
select
    'And every where that Mary went Status changed from 2 to 8 45 Address Street'  --SourceID = 2, DestinationID = 8
```

Comment: I believe you will want to use regex on a repeating number followed by space by to by repeating number. Then split on space to pull 1st and 3rd elements. Using `from` is not enough of a identifier. Your text could have from anywhere that does not fit the pattern of `from # to #`. Regex also assumes you will never have a pattern of `# to #` that is not your source and destination ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any function or external RegEx you can walk this route:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
           ,CAST(CONCAT('<x><y>',REPLACE(REPLACE(LogValue,' to ','</y><y>'),' ','</y></x><x><y>'),'</y></x>') AS XML) AS CastedToXml
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT cte.*
      ,numberY.value('/y[1]','int') AS SourceID
      ,numberY.value('/y[2]','int') AS DestinationID
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CastedToXml.query('/x[not(empty(y[1] cast as xs:int?)) 
                                      and not(empty(y[2] cast as xs:int?))]/y')) A(numberY);
```

The idea in short:

- We use some replacements to transform your string into XML (treating `' to '` specially)

Click one of the XML-Hyperlinks to see the intermediate XML.

```
<x>
  <y>Status</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>changed</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>from</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>1</y>
  <y>10</y>
</x>
```

- The `APPLY` will use `.query()` to pick each `<x>`, where we find two `<y>` castable to int.
- Now we can pick the first and the second in order to return your values.

### UPDATE

Using this in the cte would add a marking attribute when `from` or `to` was there before the number:

```
,CAST(CONCAT('<x><y>',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LogValue,' from ',' to '),' to ','</y><y*>'),' ','</y></x><x><y>'),'<y*>','<y takeThis="true">'),'</y></x>') AS XML) AS CastedToXml
```

The intermediate XML would then look like this
(**attention:** I changed the input data with *noise*, such as `from Vienna to London` or numbers in other places):

```
<x>
  <y>Mary</y>
  <y takeThis="true">vienna</y>
  <y takeThis="true">london</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>had</y>
  <y takeThis="true">3</y>
</x>
<!-- shortened for brevity -->
<x>
  <y>changed</y>
  <y takeThis="true">4</y>
  <y takeThis="true">12</y>
</x>
```

This allows to avoid *false positives* (e.g. two numbers within an address)

A quite *tolerant* query was this finally:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
           ,CAST(CONCAT('<x><y>',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LogValue,' from ',' to '),' to ','</y><y*>'),' ','</y></x><x><y>'),'<y*>','<y takeThis="true">'),'</y></x>') AS XML) AS CastedToXml
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT cte.*
      ,numberY.value('/y[1]','int') AS SourceID
      ,numberY.value('/y[2]','int') AS DestinationID
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CastedToXml.query('for $x in /x[count(y[@takeThis="true"])=2]
                                       for $y in $x/y 
                                       return if(not(empty($y cast as xs:int?))) then $y else null')) A(numberY);
```

It uses a XQuery-FLWOR to reduce the set to the figures you are looking for. This will deal with disturbing other numbers in your string quite well.

The filter will look for `<x>` elements, where there are two `<y>` elements with the attribute `takeThis="true` and will return these `<y>` elements only if castable to int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
Not the cuttest code

```
select 
substring(LogValue, charindex('from',LogValue) + len('from'), charindex('to',LogValue) - charindex('from',LogValue) - len('from')) as SourceID,

case when charindex(' ',right(LogValue, len(LogValue) - (charindex('to',LogValue) + len('to')))) > 0 then
    left(right(LogValue, len(LogValue) - (charindex('to',LogValue) + len('to'))), charindex(' ',right(LogValue, len(LogValue) - (charindex('to',LogValue) + len('to')))))
else
    right(LogValue, len(LogValue) - (charindex('to',LogValue) + len('to')))
end as DestinationID 
from #temp
```

Output:

```
SourceID    DestinationID
 1            10
 4            12
 5            17 
 2            8
```

Comment: Searching for `from` and `to` and finding the numbers on both sides of `to` can be a good approach, but I would include the blanks. Otherwise you would find these tags even in the middle of a word...

Answer (score 0):

You can spend some time in implementing [SQL CLR functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) for performing operations with regular expressions (the [String Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ff878119(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is created by Microsoft and brings a lot of handy functions).

For example, you can use regex matches function to get the first and the second occurrence of number and then to pivot it:

```
SELECT [LogValue]
      ,[0] AS [SourceID]
      ,[1] AS [DestinationID]
FROM
(
    SELECT LogValue
          ,RM.[MatchID]
          ,RM.[CaptureValue]
    FROM #temp T
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] (LogValue,  '\d+') RM
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([CaptureValue]) FOR [MatchID] IN ([0], [1])
) PVT;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY` to extract the required values.

```
select PARSENAME(SD.VAL,3) AS SOURCE,PARSENAME(SD.VAL,1) AS DESTINATION from #temp
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' from ',LogValue))) FRM(LOC) -- extract the  position of 'from'
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' to ',LogValue,FRM.LOC+1))) TOO(LOC) --extract the position of 'to' after 'from'
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',LogValue,TOO.LOC+4))) SPC(LOC) -- extract the position of space 2nd space after 'to'
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRIM(SUBSTRING(LogValue,FRM.LOC, CASE WHEN SPC.LOC!=0 THEN SPC.LOC-FRM.LOC
                                                     ELSE LEN(LogValue)-FRM.LOC+1 END )))) FT(val)  --extract the words from 'from' to after value of 'to'
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(FT.VAL,' ','.'))) SD(val) -- replacing the space with dot to use PARSENAME
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8db6ac5836820749f6bbf0949726c34b)

*Output*

[image]

Comment: As commented below the other `CHARINDEX` answer (by @zip), you should add the blanks to your search strings. Otherwise you might get *false positives*...