# SQL Server : multiple rows into one column and concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I want to concatenate and transpose into one - see below. Thanks for the help/

Table 1

```
ID   Name
-----------
1    Bob
2    Rich
3    Harry
```

Table 2

```
ID Opening Time   Closing Time   Day
------------------------------------------
1  8 AM           10 AM          Sunday
1  11 AM          12 PM          Sunday
1  8 AM           11 AM          Monday
1  8 AM           11 AM          Tuesday
2  9 AM           11 AM          Sunday
2  8 AM           11 AM          Monday
3  8 AM           11 AM          Sunday
3  8 AM           11 AM          Monday
3  8 AM           11 AM          Tuesday
```

I need this result

```
ID   Name   Sunday                     Monday          Tuesday
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Bob    8 AM - 10 AM 11 AM - 12PM  8 AM - 11 AM     8 AM - 11 AM
2    Rich   9 AM - 11 AM               8 AM - 11 AM 
3    Harry  8 AM - 11 AM               8 AM - 11 AM     8 AM - 11 AM
```

Comment: which version of SQL server you are using

Answer (score 1):

Here is full working example with using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @DataSource01 TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
);

DECLARE @DataSource02 TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Opening Time] VARCHAR(8)
   ,[Closing Time] VARCHAR(8)
   ,[Day] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource01 ([ID], [Name])
VALUES (1, 'Bob')
      ,(2, 'Rich')
      ,(3, 'Harry');

INSERT INTO @DataSource02 ([ID], [Opening Time], [Closing Time], [Day])
VALUES (1, '8 AM', '10 AM', 'Sunday')
      ,(1, '11 AM', '12 PM', 'Sunday')
      ,(1, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Monday')
      ,(1, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Tuesday')
      ,(2, '9 AM', '11 AM', 'Sunday')
      ,(2, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Monday')
      ,(3, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Sunday')
      ,(3, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Monday')
      ,(3, '8 AM', '11 AM', 'Tuesday');

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DS1.[ID]
          ,DS1.[Name]
          ,DS2.[Day]
          ,STRING_AGG(DS2.[Opening Time] + ' ' + DS2.[Closing Time], '')
    FROM @DataSource01 DS1
    INNER JOIN @DataSource02 DS2
        ON DS1.[ID] = DS2.[ID]
    GROUP BY DS1.[ID]
            ,DS1.[Name]
            ,DS2.[Day]
) DS ([ID], [Name], [Day], [Time])
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Time]) FOR [Day] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday])
) PVT
ORDER BY [ID];
```

If the `days` vary, you can use `dynamic pivot` or list all of them. Also, if you are using earlier then SQL Server 2017, you need to concatenate the vales with `XML` or `SQL CLR` [string aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692940/remove-weird-characters-a-with-hat-from-sql-server-varchar-column/31693412#31693412).

[image]