# What is "assembly stored procedure" type mean?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server database with a lot of stored procedures. I use the system stored procedure `sp_help` to view information about these stored procedures.

There are a lot of stored procedure that have type = 'stored procedure' in information view, but some of the stored procedures have type 'assembly stored procedure'.

1. What is the difference between them?
2. And what is the purpose of using that type of stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you are able to create [SQL CLR objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=cs), which basically allows you to create .NET routines (functions, stored procedures, triggers and even custom aggregates).

For example, you can use .NET to implement [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) functions, or in the past, when [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) did not exist, to create custom aggregate for string concatenation.