# understanding query to remove non-numeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I find very helpful post, how to remove non-numeric characters from string:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18635337/6216435

But few questions arose, hopefully someone can explain a bit.
1) Why to use this:

```
select top (100) N=row_number() over (order by @@spid) from sys.all_columns)
```

Results gives numbers 1-100, but why @@spid and sys.all_columns? Is there better way to do it?

2) `..where N<=datalength(DirtyCol)) [1] where C between '0' and '9'` - what does [1] represents here?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: sys.all_columns is a system table which contains metadata,it is used as a dummy table to generate data(it has many rows).For your second question [1] is an alias for that subquery it might as well have been [RandomName]- the `as` is implicit, `(subquery) as SomeName`

Comment: `[` and `]` are used around names in sql server -- for some reason this guy wanted to name this table "1" -- mostly I think it just made the code harder to read.  I would have substituted `tmp` for `[1]`   If it isn't a number you don't need the brackets and tmp is a good description of the table.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to post these questions as a comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

That answer is using `@@spid` as a constant value, similar to `order by (select`)`

It is using sys.all_columns just for a source of 100 rows to generate the row numbers.

Here are some articles where Aaron Bertrand benchmarks alternatives for generating a set or sequence:

[Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1 - Aaron Bertrand - 2013-01-16](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

[Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2 - Aaron Bertrand - 2013-01-17](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

[Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3 - Aaron Bertrand - 2013-01-18](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)