# How to trim/replace any letters in the value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have few columns in my old database that have values where number and letters are combined together. This is something that I have to clean and import in the new table. The most of the values that need to be converted look like this:

```
40M or 85M or NR or 5NR ...
```

Since there wasn't any validation what user can enter in the old system there still can be values like: 40A or 3R and so on. I want to import only numeric values in my new table. So if there is any letters in the value I want to trim them. What is the best way to do that in SQL Server? I have tried this:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('M',hs_ptr1) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hs_ptr1
```

but this will only identify if one letter is in the value. If anyone can help please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server patindex`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL select query to remove non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/t-sql-select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `patindex` to search for the pattern. Try this code:

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      TXT NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (TXT)
VALUES 
    ('40M'),
    ('85M'),
    ('NR'),
    ('5NR')

SELECT LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1) 
FROM (
    SELECT subsrt = SUBSTRING(TXT, pos, LEN(TXT))
    FROM (
        SELECT TXT, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TXT)
        FROM #temp
    ) d
) t

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way without a function....

```
declare @table table (c varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('40M'),
('30'),
('5NR'),
('3(-4_')

select
replace(LEFT(SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',','')), 8000),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',','')), 8000) + 'X') -1),'.','')
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You go with the [`PATINDEX` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql#examples) and search for a character that is not a digit. If such an index exists, then grab everything to the left of it. Something like that:

```
SELECT LEFT(your_field_name, PATINDEX("%[^0-9]%", your_field_name) - 1)
FROM your_table_name
```

## UPDATE

Well, you need to take care of any edge cases. E.g. if there isn't a non-digit data the function will return 0, thus the calculation yields -1, which, indeed, is an invalid length.

I would suggest you to leverage a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to calculate the index of the non-digit data and then construct an [IIF expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) to select the correct char data. E.g.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, PATINDEX("%[^0-9]%", your_field_name) AS NumLength
    FROM your_table_name
)
SELECT any_other_field, IIF(NumLength = 0, 
    your_field_name, 
    LEFT(your_field_name, PATINDEX("%[^0-9]%", your_field_name) - 1)
)
FROM cte
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message: Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.