# How to Join Table with Different Length of ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two columns that look like this :

Table_1

| termid | Nominal | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 75.000.000 | 1 |
| 123 | 11.432.105.000 | 61 |
| 2345 | 339.660.000 | 3 |
| 234 | 199.800.000 | 2 |
| 12345 | 3.760.079.000 | 29 |

Table_2

| tid | type | region | locatin | merk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00012345 | PSW01 | Jakarta I | JKT1-LANTAMAL | HYOSUNG |
| DTBA234 | EDC | Jakarta I | JKT1-RKB BRI | HYOSUNG |
| 00001234 | PSW01 | Jakarta I | JKT1-APOTIK KIMIA FARMA | HYOSUNG |
| EDC2345 | EDC | Jakarta III | JKT1-KPU JAKARTA PUSAT | WINCOR |
| 00000123 | PSW01 | Jakarta I | JKT-SPBU CIDENG | HYOSUNG |

So i want to left join the table with this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2
ON t1.Termid = CAST(t2.tid AS INT)
```

The query can run perfectly when I exclude the EDC type. But since I want to concatenate the whole line, I'm having an error like:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DTBA234' to data type int.

I know that the error is because there are characters other than numeric. But I don't know how to solve like the above case.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

** Note : Sorry for my english

Comment: How do you want join the table ? By removing the alphabet in `tid` ?

Comment: maybe [isnumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can help

Comment: Yes, by removing the alphabet

Comment: Does the alphabet only appear in-front of the string or maybe in middle or at the back ? Please show more samples data of such case

Comment: But please when giving a [mre] the input tables should be given as initialization code in code block format in columns. So we & you can cut & paste & run the whole example but also read the input as tables. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Give minimal representative data. (Less than now.) PS This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: The alphabet only appear in front and middle of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the integer from the `tid` column of `Table_2` and join with the `termid` column of `Table_1`.

Assuming the integer value in the `tid` column will be together, you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2
ON t1.Termid = CAST(SUBSTRING(t2.tid, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t2.tid), LEN(t2.tid)) AS INT)
```

NOTE: If `tid` has any value like `EDC2345DBTA123`, this won't work.

Comment: So how to remove alphanumeric from `EDC2345DBTA123` like this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Sql Server doesnt support regexp_replace like other dbs theres no direct way but alternatively you can use `SUBSTRING(id, Patindex...)`  like below reference :

[How to find and remove alphabet letters in in a column on MS sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274318/how-to-find-and-remove-alphabet-letters-in-in-a-column-on-ms-sql-server)