# SQL Phone Number Conversion

Tags: sql

I have phone numbers in a SQL database stored in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format. is there any way to cast these as xxxxxxxxxx format instead?

Comment: You can use `REPLACE` function to achieve.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/t-sql-select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters

Comment: How did this get 2 upvotes? "Remove non-numeric characters SQL", 'format phone numbers SQL', any of those Google searches show anything?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `REPLACE()` function :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('(XXX) XXX-XXXX','(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','')
```

Comment: This could be shorter by using MySQL's REGEXP REPLACE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql, but it's only available for MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle or MySQL 8+, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('(914) 591-8563', '\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})', '\1\2\3')
FROM dual;

9145918563
```

This solution works via regex by capturing the 10 digits, and then generating a replacement of only digits.  Explore the demo below using either Oracle or MySQL 8+:

### Demo