# How to remove any character then number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with data like:

```
401-305-3069703-1---------------------------------------------------------
1-1499964-305-395---------------------------------------------------------
1-14995964-4405-395---------------------------------------------------------
....
```

How I can remove all dash and any character after last number like:

```
401-305-3069703-1
1-1499964-305-395
1-14995964-4405-395
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/t-sql-select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters

Comment: thanks but i need  401-305-3069703-1 and - between number is non-numeric

Comment: Refer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like following using `PATINDEX` and `REVERSE`

```
SELECT LEFT(@str, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@str)) +1)
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/WFJEOH95455)

Here [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is being used to find the last occurrence of any number using wildcard pattern, as there are multiple numbers and we want to find the last number index so we are reversing it using `REVERSE` before applying the [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Once the index is found, using `LEFT` we are getting the substring from the text.