# Filter IDs with just numbers excluding letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have results that begins with 2 letters followed by 3 numbers, for example:

```
ID_Sample
AB001
BC003
AB100
BC400
```

How can I do a query that ignores the letters and just looks up the numbers to do a filter? For example:

```
WHERE ID_Sample >= 100
```

I tried using a "Replace" to get rid of known letters, but I figured there might be a better way. For example:

```
Select
   Replace(id_sample,'AB','')
```

Choosing the 3 numerals on the right would work too.

Comment: Sure, just included it. Tried using "Replace", figured I could just put that in a subfilter then filter based on the values. But, was hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: Performance will be terrible in a `where` clause because it has to run the computation on every record in the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL select query to remove non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/t-sql-select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample data, you can just start at the third character and convert to a number:

```
where try_convert(int, stuff(ID_Sample, 1, 2, '')) > 100
```

Or, if you know that the number is 3 characters:

```
where try_convert(int, right(ID_Sample, 3)) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Gordon's answer. This is a fun problem that you can solve using [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you're using SQL 2017+.

First, in case you've never used it, Per [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `TRANSLATE`:

> Returns the string provided as a first argument after some characters
>   specified in the second argument are translated into a destination set
>   of characters specified in the third argument.[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**This:**

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('123AABBCC!!!','ABC','XYZ');
```

**Returns:** 123XXYYZZ!!!

Here's the solution using TRANSLATE:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID_Sample CHAR(6))
INSERT @t (ID_Sample) VALUES ('AB001'),('BC003'),('AB100'),('BC400'),('CC555');

-- Solution
SELECT 
  ID_Sample     = t.ID_Sample,
  ID_Sample_Int = s.NewString
FROM         @t AS t
CROSS JOIN  (VALUES('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', REPLICATE(0,26)))     AS f(S1,S2)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CAST(TRANSLATE(t.ID_Sample,f.S1,f.S2) AS INT))) AS s(NewString)
WHERE        s.NewString >= 100;
```

Without the WHERE clause filter you get:

```
ID_Sample ID_Sample_Int
--------- -------------
AB001     1
BC003     3
AB100     100
BC400     400
CC555     555
```

... the WHERE clause filters out the first two rows.

Answer (score 1):

Check these methods- Unit test also done!

```
Declare @Table as table(ID_Sample varchar(20))

set nocount on

Insert into @Table (ID_Sample)
Values('AB001'),('BC003'),('AB100'),('BC400')

--substring_method
select * from @Table 
where try_cast(substring(ID_Sample,3,3) as int) >100

--right_method
select * from @Table 
where try_cast(right(ID_Sample,3) as int) >100

--stuff_method
select * from @Table 
where try_cast(stuff(ID_Sample,1,2,'') as int) >100

--replace_method
select * from @Table 
where try_cast(replace(ID_Sample,left(ID_Sample,2),'') as int) >100
```