# Filter columns before calculating SUM (Error: Error converting data type varchar to int)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, information-schema, dynamicquery

I need to calculate Min/Max/etc. values for columns in my a table. So I want to filter the columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get only the numeric ones.

The following query returns an error: *Error converting data type varchar to int.* and I don't know how to fix it.

```
SELECT @vQuery = 
'SELECT  '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TableName 
    , '''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS ColumnName
    , '''+DATA_TYPE+''' AS DataType
    , MIN(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(['+COLUMN_NAME+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NUMERIC(30,4))) AS MinValue
    , MAX(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(['+COLUMN_NAME+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NUMERIC(30,4))) AS MaxValue
    , AVG(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(['+COLUMN_NAME+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NUMERIC(30,4))) AS AvgValue
    , STDEV(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(['+COLUMN_NAME+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NUMERIC(30,4))) AS StandardDeviation
    , SUM(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(['+COLUMN_NAME+'] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NUMERIC(30,4))) AS TotalSum
FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+';'+ CHAR(10)         
FROM 
(SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
AND TABLE_NAME = @Table
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('BIGINT','NUMERIC','SMALLINT','DECIMAL','SMALLMONEY','INTEGER','INT','TINYINT','MONEY','FLOAT','REAL')) t
```

Comment: This  thread may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Why are you converting the value to a string before converting to a numeric?  That has nothing to do with the error, but it seems rather awkward.

Comment: I suppose you mean you get an error when you execute the string in variable `@vQuery`. Do us and yourself a favour, and `print` the value of the string you attempt to execute.

Comment: The query you have written should properly construct the SQL:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7987d9cce5b8d59a30b3fd1be8dc7880.

Comment: Also, you select the columns of a table, but the variable will only hold the information from the last row of that result set (which one that is is unpredicatable)

Comment: Careful, thiis is still wide open to injection. You use `QUOTENAME` for the `FROM` but don't for the rest of the query. You need to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't want to write separate query for each data type. Isn't it possible to do this with a dynamic query?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment:

Your query appears to work [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77b7cb0b6005cfe6687486a6b37b38ca).

If you were not using the `try_()` functions, then the problem might occur when you *run* the query but not when you generate it.  And the issue is exponential notation.  For instance:

```
select convert(varchar(255), convert(float, 1234556678990.0))
```

returns:

```
'1.23456e+012'
```

And this value cannot be converted to a numeric value.

I see no advantage to converting to a string before converting to a numeric, so I would drop those conversions.  However, with `try_cast()` this should not be an issue.

In fact, you are generating *separate* queries for each type.  I don't think any conversion is warranted.  The queries can return different types if they want.  You would need to be concerned about types if you connected the queries using `UNION ALL`.

Note:  You should also use `QUOTENAME()` on the column names.  It can protect against SQL injection, but that seems like a very unlikely problem when you are selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables (someone would have to create very curious table/column names).  However, it also handles non-conforming column names, such as those with spaces.

Comment: I converted to VARCHAR first because in another case I had problem directly converting to NUMERIC. And if you try to run the query and have datetime column, it will show the error I am talking about.

Comment: This is why I want to filter out columns that are not numeric type.

Comment: I removed try_cast but still get the same error that I am converting varchar/datetime to int. I need to make the calculations only for numeric columns.

Comment: This could occur if `@vQuery`, `@Schema`, or `@Table` where declared as integers, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: They are `NVARCHAR` type.