# How to update a column supposed to be only numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to transform the values of a column in my table which is supposed to contain only numbers. It is the "TEL" column.
This column currently has special characters and spaces. I need to filter this.

The additional constraint is that if the very first character (only the first character) is a "+" I would have to transform the + into "00"

You will find below an example of what is expected.

Could you please help me to create such a query?

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsInitial (
    tel varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255)
);

insert into PersonsInitial(tel,firstname,lastname) values
('+41/ jfakl2 eaf3efa54844','Manu','Johns'),
('01-afe fa-e8fa5a +e5+ e+234','Fernand','Wajk'),
(' +41/34 jfakl2 eaf3efa54844','Fred','Johns')

;

select tel, firstname, lastname from PersonsInitial

--if there is a person with the same tel number chose the customer id with 'C'
--if I don't have the choice add the customer without C

CREATE TABLE PersonsFinal (
    tel varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255))
;

insert into PersonsFinal(tel,firstname,lastname) values
('00412354844','Manu','Johns'),
('01855234','Fernand','Wajk'),
('0041342354844','Fred','Johns')

;
select tel, firstname, lastname from PersonsFinal
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8d1f41928be9d94b57033f8b1fe046e)

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters

Comment: Side point: `+` and `00` are *not* the same thing in telephone numbers. In many phone systems (such as the UK) they have the same *meaning*, but they aren't the same. See also https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a User-Defined Function for this.

For example:

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCleanTel (@Input VARCHAR(255))
> RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(255) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Input));
>   
>   IF LEFT(@Output, 1) = '+'
>     SET @Output = STUFF(@Output,1,1,'00');
>     
>   WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Output) > 0
>     SET @Output = REPLACE(@Output, SUBSTRING(@Output,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Output),1),'');
>   
>   RETURN @Output;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PersonsFinal (
>     tel varchar(255),
>     firstname varchar(255),
>     lastname varchar(255)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into PersonsFinal (tel, firstname, lastname) 
> select dbo.fnCleanTel(tel) as clean_tel, firstname, lastname 
> from PersonsInitial;
>
> select tel, firstname, lastname from PersonsFinal
> ```
>
> ```
> tel           | firstname | lastname
> :------------ | :-------- | :-------
> 00412354844   | Manu      | Johns   
> 01855234      | Fernand   | Wajk    
> 0041342354844 | Fred      | Johns
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=696921c5fafb4b94fe96b9043a025e41)*

Comment: You can simplify LTRIM(RTRIM(@Input)); to TRIM(@Input);

Comment: @Kendle I prefere RTRIM & LTRIM for the simple reason that TRIM only got intruduced with Sql Server 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that `translate` is useful for. You can define a string of characters to remove and replace them all with a single character also to be removed, eg a space, with some additional logic for your initial `00` criteria:

```
declare @replace varchar(30)='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/+-';

select *, 
  Replace(Translate(Iif(Left(Replace(tel,' ',''),1)='+',Concat('00',tel),tel), @replace, Replicate(' ',Len(@replace))),' ','')
from PersonsInitial;
```

You can then use an Updatable CTE to fix the original data, see example in [Amended DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1050a36cf89eeb58962d8dc1eb1c303)

I'd suggest once you have fixed your data you use a *Check Constraint* to ensure only valid data can be used.