# convert varchar to INT SQL -Conversion Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, type-conversion, sql-function

I am trying to convert varchar to Int and i tried cast, convert, try_cast but getting an error conversion failed when converting varchar to datatype INT.Any other way to convert it?

```
select cast('123RA' as INT) as p
```

Comment: you can have any non numeric characters in the text for the conversion to succed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters how to remove them

Answer (score 1):

We have to remove non-numeric characters to be able to cast to int.

> ```
> SELECT 
> textval,
> cast(
>   LEFT(SUBSTRING(textval, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', textval), 8000),
>            PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(textval, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', textval), 8000) + 'X') -1)
>   as int) numval
> from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> textval | numval
> :------ | -----:
> 123RA   |    123
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ec5a9ec8c88e65b866d84bd46681e8c)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply .But I need nonnumeric characters.

Comment: then you must explain in your question the wanted result

Comment: This answer does what you need, what does "I need nonnumeric characters" mean? You are asking to convert the string to an integer. What do you expect??

Comment: @learner123 so you want to cast non-numeric values to a numeric datatype, and you are surprised you can't? Do you know what datatypes are?