# Is there any SQLite function for fetching the numeric value from alphanumeric character?

Tags: sqlite

> There is an alphanumeric character '**(123) 456-789 (sou_rav)**'  and output will be '**123456789**' (there should not be any special character) by using SQLite. SQLite version is 3.31.1

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| (123) 456-789 (sou_rav) | 123456789 |

> I have tried below query but it's not working. Expecting out put is '123456789'

```
select replace(replace(replace('(123) 456-789 (sou_rav)', rtrim('(123) 456-789 (sou_rav)', '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!#$%^&*()_+-=`~[]\/{}|;:,.<>?'),''),'(',''),')','') as a from table_name;
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't have programmable functions or procedures. If you have a lot of rows, you could perhaps export to a database engine that has ? [example for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters). Or, use a programming language to process the data in your SQLite.

Comment: It's usually easier to do any processing like that in the code that's handling the results of a sqlite query rather in the query itself.