# trim values from left using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to trim the characters from the left in my SQL value:

I have the following value:

```
ABC0005953
```

How do i trim the value 3 characters from the left? I would like to see:

```
005953
```

Edit my value is:

```
SELECT LEN(TABLE.VALUE)-3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to remove non-numeric characters from a VARCHAR in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106206/fastest-way-to-remove-non-numeric-characters-from-a-varchar-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC0005953', 4, LEN('ABC0005953'))
```

Start at the fourth character and keep going.

(Just posting as an alternative to the `RIGHT(...)` solution.)

In response to your update, I assume you mean you want to apply the above to your table:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(TABLE.VALUE, 4, LEN(TABLE.VALUE))
FROM TABLE
```

From your other question:

> I have the following:
>
> SELECT DISTINCT
>
> Left(GIFTHEADER.pID + GIFTHEADER.PID + '-' + Cast(PAYMENTDETAIL.PLINENO as Varchar),18)
>
> AS TRANSACTIONREF...
>
> Currently my value looks like this:
>
> ABC0005953ABC0005953
>
> I want to simply strip off the first 4 characters from GIFTHEADER.pID

If you want to remove the first four characters from `GIFTHEADER.pID`, I would recommend removing them before putting the value into your combined string:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(GIFTHEADER.pID, 5, LEN(GIFTHEADER.pID) +
        GIFTHEADER.PID +
        '-' +
        Cast(PAYMENTDETAIL.PLINENO as Varchar),18)
    AS TRANSACTIONREF
```

Comment: @PriceCheaperton:  Modified answer based on your `TABLE.VALUE`.

Comment: Left ((LEN(COLUMN.ID)-3) + COLUMNHEADER.ID + '-' + Cast(STUFFDETAIL.COLUMNLINENO as Varchar),18)

Comment: i NEED TO apply it to that? Sorry once again!

Comment: @PriceCheaperton:  I'm not sure I understand.  You're building a text value and you want to remove.. what from it?

Comment: I want to strip away the ABC0... Ie remove the 4 characters from the right.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton:  Your question says three characters.  Just change the `4` to a `5`, and replace `TABLE.VALUE` with your expression.  You may want to use a subquery to prevent creating the column more than once.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton:  Edited based on your other question.

Comment: This seems to be truncating my giftheader.pID value... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STUFF` function to replace chars 1 thru 3 with an empty string

```
SELECT STUFF('ABC0005953',1,3,'')
```

I believe it's a better and more universal approach than cutting string.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('ABC0005953', LEN('ABC0005953') - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could could just use right(x, len(x)-3)

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC0005953', 5,7)

SELECT RIGHT('ABC0005953', (LEN('ABC0005953') - 4))
```