# remove trailing chars to get numeric value

Tags: string, t-sql, sql-server-2012, isnull

I'm struggling to combine two expression into one so that I can remove trailing **'mm'** chars of a varchar column which holds values like **3.214mm** and use those chars as numeric values.

The problem I have is that there can be also null or empty string values and I can't find a way to combine both expressions below.

Example: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0764/15)

```
DECLARE @string varchar(128)
SET @string = '4.123mm'
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(@string,''),NULL) As MyString ;

DECLARE @createNumber varchar(128)
SET @createNumber = '4.123mm'
select LEFT(@createNumber, NULLIF (LEN(@createNumber) - 2, - 1))As MyNumber
```

Comment: A bit tacky, but do you know the measurements are "mm"? Might consider Replace of "mm" with "".

Comment: Also some interesting ideas if a bit procedural here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106206/fastest-way-to-remove-non-numeric-characters-from-a-varchar-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @createNumber varchar(128)
SET @createNumber = ''
select reverse(stuff(reverse(@createNumber), 1,2, ''))
```

This will return null if createnumber is shorter than 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle mm/''/null;

```
select cast(isnull(replace('0' + @createNumber, 'mm', ''), 0) as decimal(6,3))
```