# Replacing set of character in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do i replace set of character in a table?

```
ColumnA
%%1234UIT
!!1234TTT
678@@PPP
```

Currently I am using

```
`replace(replace(replace([BLOCK_NAME],'%%',''),'!!',''),'@@',''),1,LEN(BLOCK_NAME)-1`
OR
replace(replace(replace(substring([BLOCK_NAME],1,LEN(BLOCK_NAME)-1),'**',''),'##',''),'$$','')
```

> ```
> Expected OUTPUT:
> 1234UIT
> 123TTT
> 678PPP
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to remove all non-numeric characters?

Comment: What's the expected output? The expression you've shown is incomplete - it looks like you've stripped out maybe a `SUBSTRING` call? Because your expression currently is `<nested replace>,number,number`

Comment: @unlimit no just those specified characters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. I escaped substring. I just want to know if there is single function doing all the replacing.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your problem, it removes all non numeric characters from the record. You can create a sql function to be called from your query.

```
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
END
RETURN @strText
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [how to remove non-numeric/non-alphanumeric characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106206/fastest-way-to-remove-non-numeric-characters-from-a-varchar-in-sql-server)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

---

select data using the created function

```
SELECT 
    dbo.fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters(BLOCK_NAME)
FROM 
    YourTable
```

OR

```
;WITH T as(
  SELECT STUFF(BLOCK_NAME, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', BLOCK_NAME), 1, '') BLOCK_NAME from YourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT STUFF(BLOCK_NAME, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', BLOCK_NAME), 1, '') BLOCK_NAME from T where PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', BLOCK_NAME) > 0
)
select 
    * 
from 
    T 
where PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', BLOCK_NAME) = 0
```

I prefer the second method using CTE without a user-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RemoveCharacters]
(
    @Str NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'

    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @Str) > 0
        SET @Str = Stuff(@Str, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @Str), 1, '')

    RETURN @Str

END

Go
```

and then call it as:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_RemoveCharacters](ColumnA, '%%!!@@') as ColumnA
from table1
```

Hope this helps!!!