# I can't update values in a column with their trimmed version. Why?

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database. In the database, there is a table, say 'MyTable'. In MyTable, there is a column, say 'MyColumn'. Its type is Text. Some data in this column have several space characters at their end, so I want to trim them. I ran the command below

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = trim(MyColumn)
```

The command was executed successfully, but I see no change. The data with space suffix are still there. Why?

Many thanks in advance,

Haris

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you have a fixed-length field (which can be created programmatically). Another is that your spaces aren't true spaces but other characters (NBSP for instance) which just 'look' like spaces.

Comment: How to remove these space-like characters then?

Comment: Space like characters are often Chr(255) you can check for this with Mid, Left & Right functions. You can then use replace, if this is the case: replace(s,chr(255),"")

Comment: Yes. 160 is another one, I think.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315/t-sql-trim-nbsp-and-other-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: You can find out the character that is at the end of the field with Asc(Right(MyColumn, 1)).