# Split numbers from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have my table like this

```
4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione
10-Contrassegno
12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno
10-Contrassegno
12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno
```

I want to split every row to be like this

```
4-3-2
10
12-10
10
12-10
```

Comment: Do you mean extract digital out from string?

Comment: did you try searching for similar questions because there are tons like this one ..

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch is right - there are many similar questions - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106206/fastest-way-to-remove-non-numeric-characters-from-a-varchar-in-sql-server), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315/t-sql-trim-nbsp-and-other-non-alphanumeric-characters) and much more found using simple search.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      SomeText VARCHAR(500)
    )
INSERT  INTO @table
        ( SomeText )
VALUES  ( '4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione' ),
        ( '10-Contrassegno' ),
        ( '12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno' ),
        ( '10-Contrassegno' ),
        ( '12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno' );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   n = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   n + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    n <= 100
             ),
        SplitToChr
          AS ( SELECT   T.ID ,
                        SUBSTRING(T.SomeText, cte.n, 1) AS Chr
               FROM     @table AS T
                        JOIN cte ON DATALENGTH(T.SomeText) >= cte.n
                                    AND SUBSTRING(T.SomeText, cte.n, 1) LIKE '[0-9-]'
             )
    SELECT   T.ID ,
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(T.FInal),2,LEN(T.FInal))) AS Final
    FROM    ( SELECT  DISTINCT
                        o.ID ,
                        REPLACE(( SELECT    '' + chr
                                  FROM      SplitToChr AS i
                                  WHERE     i.id = o.id
                                FOR
                                  XML PATH('')
                                ), '--', '-') AS FInal
              FROM      SplitToChr AS o
            ) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(STRINGCOLUMN NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT '4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione'
UNION ALL
SELECT '10-Contrassegno'
UNION ALL
SELECT '12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno'
UNION ALL
SELECT '10-Contrassegno'
UNION ALL
SELECT '12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno'
```

You can use a function in case you need the query to be simple

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToNumber]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN    
SET @strAlphaNumeric = LEFT(@strAlphaNumeric,
LEN(@strAlphaNumeric) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@strAlphaNumeric)) + 0)
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]-%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]-%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

And your final query

```
SELECT DBO.ConvertToNumber(STRINGCOLUMN)STRINGCOLUMN
FROM #TEMP
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Regarding your final query, that "ConvertToNumber" is code from C#, not from T-SQL :-)

Comment: I didn't get u. What did u mean by **ConvertToNumber is code from C#**? Is there any problem here? @ Claudio

Comment: ConvertToNumber doesn't exist in T-SQL, I can see you wrote that in your final query section :)

Comment: That is a **USER-DEFINED** function. I think you have not used functions in SQL Server. SQL Server supports function like C#, by which we call function be passing parameters to function to get desired output. @Claudio

Comment: Of course I've used UDF's in SQL Server...but I never had to nor did I know that you can use C# code inside it !!! :-)  @Sarath Avanavu

Answer (score 0):

first use this split func

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] ( @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
,                                       @delimiter CHAR(1) )
RETURNS @output TABLE ( splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start INT
    ,       @end   INT
    SELECT @start = 1
    ,      @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1
    BEGIN
        IF @end = 0
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output ( splitdata                                 )
        VALUES              ( SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start) )
        SET @start = @end + 1
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END
    RETURN
END
```

and then use this code

```
CREATE TABLE #t10 ( id  int identity(1,1)
,                   num int )
INSERT INTO #t10
select *
from dbo.fnSplitString ('4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione','-')
WHERE ISNUMERIC(splitdata)=1
DECLARE @x int = 1
DECLARE @y varchar(10)=''
DECLARE @q varchar(10)
WHILE @x<=(SELECT count(*)
    from #t10)
BEGIN
    SET @q=(SELECT num
    FROM #t10
    WHERE id = @x )
    set @y=@y+@q+'-'
    SET @x=@x+1
END
SELECT left(ltrim(@y),len(@y)-1)
--SELECT * FROM #t10
--drop table #t10
```

Comment: Of all the possible ways to split a string in sql the while loop is the worst performing method to use. I would suggest changing your function for ANY of the faster options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: well you said ANY -i check my splitter against '[dbo].[SplitStrings_CTE]' and the execution plan looks the same.

Comment: If you are ok with using code that has been demonstrated to be slower than other code it is fine with me. It is your system that is slowed down by that not mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy, but it gets the job done :-)

```
            CREATE TABLE dbo.Documents (
            Details VARCHAR(1000)
            );


            GO

            INSERT INTO dbo.Documents
            VALUES ('4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione'),
                   ('10-Contrassegno'),
                   ('12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno'),
                   ('10-Contrassegno'),
                   ('12-Documenti di annullo polizza-10-Contrassegno');



             SELECT CASE WHEN (FirstLine + SecondLine +  ThirdLine) LIKE '%-' 
                    THEN LEFT(FirstLine + SecondLine +  ThirdLine, LEN(FirstLine + SecondLine +  ThirdLine) -1)
                    ELSE (FirstLine + SecondLine +  ThirdLine) END AS CleanData
             FROM (  

               SELECT 
                LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)) AS FirstLine,
             REPLACE(CASE 
                        WHEN REPLACE(  REPLACE( LEFT(Details,CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details )+1)+2)     ,    LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)+1)),    ''), LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)),  '') LIKE '%[0-9]' THEN   REPLACE(  REPLACE( LEFT(Details,CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details )+1)+2)     ,    LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)+1)),    ''), LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)),  '') + '-'
               ELSE  REPLACE( LEFT(Details,CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details )+1)+2)     ,    LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)+1)),    '')
               END , LEFT(Details, CHARINDEX('-', Details)),  '') AS SecondLine,
               CASE  WHEN REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Details), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Details))+2)) LIKE '-%'
                THEN LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Details), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Details))+2)), 3) ELSE '' END  AS ThirdLine
               FROM dbo.Documents 
               ) AS A;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing it in a much simpler way. Create a `function` to remove the `alphabets` from the string

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.RemoveAlphabets (@string VARCHAR(256))
returns VARCHAR(256)
  BEGIN
      IF @string  IS NULL
        RETURN NULL

      DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(256)='',@len INT = Len(@string ),@cnt INT=1

      WHILE @cnt <= @len
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @parse INT
            SET @parse = Ascii(Substring(@string , @cnt, 1))

            IF @parse BETWEEN 48 AND 57 or @parse =45
             SET @Result =  @Result + Char(@parse) 

            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
        END
        select @result= replace(@Result,'--','-')
      RETURN left(@result,case when right(@Result,1)='-' then len(@Result)-1 else len(@result) end) 
  END
```

If numbers inside the string is always surrounded by '-' then replace the `return` statement with this.

```
 RETURN left(@result,len(@Result)-1)
```

execute the function

```
select dbo.RemoveAlphabets
('4-Documento d’identità-3-Attestato di Rischio-2-Carta di Circolazione')
```

***Result*** : `4-3-2`