# SQL Server : how to remove leading/trailing non-alphanumeric characters from string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am using SQL Server 2008, and try to sanitize a list of urls.

Some existing examples of texts:

```
www.google.com
'www.google.com'
/www.google.com
www.google.com/
```

Ideally I can strip any leading/trailing non-alphanumeric characters so the four would give out the same output as

```
www.google.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL trim &nbsp (and other non-alphanumeric characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315/t-sql-trim-nbsp-and-other-non-alphanumeric-characters)?

Comment: will there only ever be a single non alpha-numeric value, or could there be multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you know they are only at the beginning and end, you can do:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from (values ('www.google.com'), ('''www.google.com'''), ('/www.google.com')) v(text)
     )
select t.text, v2.text2
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.text, 1, patindex('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', t.text) - 1, ''))
     ) v(text1) cross apply
     (values (case when v.text1 like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
                   then stuff(v.text1, len(text) + 1 - patindex('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', reverse(v.text1)), len(v.text1), '')
                   else v.text1
              end)
     ) v2(text2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa1a2ffd6239246184360358f2b2624b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think there is a parentheses missing on patindex (next to last line). [db fiddle with fix, though results aren't what I'd expect](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3c9156664f0276d0f04d4733840b12e)

Comment: @scsimon . . . I always get these things wrong in SQL Server until I test them.  The answer works now.

Comment: UV from me cause it'll prob suffice their needs. It won't work for some cases, semicolon, colon, trailing braces, odd stuff.

Comment: @scsimon . . . This will remove any characters *not mentioned* in the character class in the code.  So it removes and leading or trailing semicolons, colons, trailing braces and anything else that is not a-z, A-Z, or 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `replace()` ?:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '''', ''), '/', '')
```

Comment: You'd need to account for all non-alpha numeric though, no?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Substring. Calculating length can be tricky:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (val varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 ('www.google.com'),('''www.google.com'''),('/www.google.com'),('www.google.com/'),('[www.google.com];')

SELECT SUBSTRING(val
                ,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', val) --start at position
                ,LEN(val) + 2 - PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', val) 
                  - PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', REVERSE(val)) --length of substring
                ) AS [Result]
  FROM @temp
```

Produces output:

```
Result
--------------
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
```